# How can I search path of folders where a particular git branch is created?

Tags: git, branch, git-branch

In Git, how could I search for path of directory where particular branch is created..?

Actually there is a git branch on which all the changes were carried out. Now i wanted to know on which directory the branch is created(so that i can track the folder paths), is there any way to grep the git for directory path? currently i have to move to each directory and have to manual test the same using **git branch -a**.  i refer [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/372506/how-can-i-search-git-branches-for-a-file-or-directory)

Comment: I have a feeling you are mixing up branch and directory trees. A branch isn't a folder, it's a snapshot of your whole working tree (i.e. it's a reference on a commit, which in turn points on the root tree of your working directory). Could you rephrase?

Answer (score 0):

Branches are not created on a directory.  Branches are created at some commit.

Assuming that the branch is call `your-branch` and that is was created at some point on `master`, and there are no merges, you could `git merge-base master your-branch` to find the commit.   This will find the common ancestor.

This was covered in [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3998883/git-how-to-find-commit-hash-where-branch-originated-from).

If `your-branch` has merges, the command above will not be the creation commit.  If this is the case you can do `git reflog show --no-abbrev your-branch | tail -1 | sed 's/ .*//'`.  This only works for local branches.