# Replicate IntelliJ merge commit details functionality in CLI + vanilla git

Tags: git, intellij-idea, git-merge

IntelliJ has very convenient Git log functionality for inspecting merge commit details (see screenshot below + https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/log-tab.html#changedFiles).

It shows "combined diff", a comparison of merge result to each of parent commits (#1, #2) - basically it is contents of `git show merge_commit_sha -m`

My questions:

1. how can i precisely replicate combined diff for merge commit we see at #3 (resulting contents + parents contents for ALL files involved in merge), using just cli + vanilla git? can it be achieved with some fancy options of `git diff` or `git show`? i have a suspicion it might be smth like `git diff --cc --combined-all-paths`?
2. how can i see historical info which particular files were conflicting during that merge (files which a person had to resolve)?

[image: intellij git log]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Per your [previous comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15277708/how-do-you-see-show-a-git-merge-conflict-resolution-that-was-done-given-a-mer/71181334#comment134876296_71181334), I proposed, to look at a merge commit (Git 2.36+, Q2 2022):

```
git log --remerge-diff <rev>^!
```

With [`^!` parent shorthand notion](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-rev-parse#_other_rev_parent_shorthand_notations) being:

> The `r1^!` notation includes commit `r1` but excludes all of its parents.
> By itself, this notation denotes the single commit `r1`.

`<rev>` is a "[revision](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-rev-parse#_specifying_revisions)", typically naming a commit object.
You would replace `<rev>` (including the `<` and `>`) with:

- a commit SHA1
- or a branch name ("refname")
- `@` (shortcut for HEAD)
- ...

In every case, in the context of this question, `<rev>` must represent a **merge commit**, a commit with (most often) 2 parents.
That `<rev>` commit represent the result of the merge between the two parents.

---

> How can I see historical info which particular files were conflicting during that merge (files which a person had to resolve)?

For that, you would need [Git 2.38, Q3 2022](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73091924/6309):

```bash
# You can list the files with conflicts and why they are in conflicts:
git merge-tree --write-tree --no-messages branch1 branch2

# You can list the files with conflicts (just their names):
git merge-tree --write-tree --no-messages --name-only branch1 branch2
```

You would replace `branch1` and `branch2` by your commit `<rev>` parents:

```
git merge-tree --write-tree --no-messages --name-only <rev>^1 <rev>^2
```

---

After [discussion](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/254119/discussion-between-vonc-and-max), the OP is after 3 commands for a given `merge_commit_sha`:

1. To see what person saw when he tried a merge, merge conflicted - as a big diff with non-conflicted + conflicted files - BEFORE person resolved any conflicts and made his merge commit

   ```
   git merge-tree --write-tree --no-messages --name-only merge_sha^1 merge_sha^2
   ```
2. To see factual diff that happened during merge conflict resolution and merge commit (person may add some fixes or even new files)

   ```
   git show --diff-merges=dense-combined merge_sha
   ```
3. to see a bulk change happened to repo with merge commit (merge commit change itself + all combined changes happened in 2 branches since the commit they diverged)

   ```
   git diff $(git merge-base merge_sha^1 merge_sha^2) merge_sha"
   ```

---

I would add also `git diff AUTO_MERGE`, with Git 2.42 (Q3 2023) documenting more pseudo-refs, including `AUTO_MERGE`.

See [commit 982ff3a](https://github.com/git/git/commit/982ff3a649221d9db79049e5823425f645b3228e), [commit 4fa1edb](https://github.com/git/git/commit/4fa1edb98820ec6ddf52b004f9d616c34a8ddfd2), [commit b7dd54a](https://github.com/git/git/commit/b7dd54a2c7df5e1dbe713807afb49fb77c9b7fc7), [commit 1ef3c61](https://github.com/git/git/commit/1ef3c61b7889e2aa76a8f0d32a88fbc09fca3b8e), [commit 6ec5f46](https://github.com/git/git/commit/6ec5f46071f793dbfa0915212b5708e2ce017053), [commit bc11bac](https://github.com/git/git/commit/bc11bac3291c4cbeb4fb475c4fdc6fe3b22ba12e) (22 May 2023) by [Philippe Blain (`phil-blain`)](https://github.com/phil-blain).
<sup>(Merged by [Junio C Hamano -- `gitster` --](https://github.com/gitster) in [commit 0899beb](https://github.com/git/git/commit/0899beb63c525c8254b2367e879cc8744092243f), 20 Jun 2023)</sup>

> ### [`Documentation`](https://github.com/git/git/commit/4fa1edb98820ec6ddf52b004f9d616c34a8ddfd2): document `AUTO_MERGE`
>
> <sup>Signed-off-by: Philippe Blain</sup>
> <sup>Signed-off-by: Junio C Hamano</sup>

> Since [5291828](https://github.com/git/git/commit/5291828df8386ebeb01039d1403d9f845d2f6e20) ("`merge-ort`: write `$GIT_DIR/AUTO_MERGE` whenever we hit a conflict", 2021-03-20, Git v2.32.0-rc0 -- [merge](https://github.com/git/git/commit/7bec8e7fa6175f51e79c55e28e6b2a547a986926)), when using the 'ort' merge strategy, the special ref `AUTO_MERGE` is written when a merge operation results in conflicts.
> This ref points to a tree recording the conflicted state of the working tree and is very useful during conflict resolution.
> However, this ref is not documented.
>
> Add some documentation for `AUTO_MERGE` in git-diff(1), git-merge(1), gitrevisions(7) and in the user manual.
>
> Also mention `AUTO_MERGE` in the "How to resolve conflicts" section, when mentioning '[`git diff`](https://github.com/git/git/blob/4fa1edb98820ec6ddf52b004f9d616c34a8ddfd2/Documentation/git-diff.txt)'<sup>([man](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-diff))</sup>.
>
> Closes: https://github.com/gitgitgadget/git/issues/1471

`git diff` now includes in its [man page](https://github.com/git/git/blob/4fa1edb98820ec6ddf52b004f9d616c34a8ddfd2/Documentation/git-diff.txt#L105-L109):

> A tree of interest is the one pointed to
> by the special ref `AUTO_MERGE`, which is written by the 'ort' merge
> strategy upon hitting merge conflicts (see [`git merge`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-merge)).
> Comparing the working tree with `AUTO_MERGE` shows changes you've made so far to resolve textual conflicts (see the examples below).
>
> `$ git diff AUTO_MERGE`: Changes in the working tree you've made to resolve textual conflicts so far.

`git merge` now includes in its [man page](https://github.com/git/git/blob/4fa1edb98820ec6ddf52b004f9d616c34a8ddfd2/Documentation/git-merge.txt#L199-L203):

> 5. A special ref `AUTO_MERGE` is written, pointing to a tree
>    corresponding to the current content of the working tree (including
>    conflict markers for textual conflicts).
>    Note that this ref is only
>    written when the 'ort' merge strategy is used (the default).

`revisions` now includes in its [man page](https://github.com/git/git/blob/4fa1edb98820ec6ddf52b004f9d616c34a8ddfd2/Documentation/revisions.txt#L75-L78):

> ### `AUTO_MERGE`:
>
> records a tree object corresponding to the state the
> 'ort' merge strategy wrote to the working tree when a merge operation
> resulted in conflicts.

`user-manual` now includes in its [man page](https://github.com/git/git/blob/4fa1edb98820ec6ddf52b004f9d616c34a8ddfd2/Documentation/user-manual.txt#L1346-L1372):

> When using the 'ort' merge strategy (the default), before updating the working
> tree with the result of the merge, Git writes a special ref named `AUTO_MERGE`
> reflecting the state of the tree it is about to write.
>
> Conflicted paths with
> textual conflicts that could not be automatically merged are written to this
> tree with conflict markers, just as in the working tree.
>
> AUTO_MERGE can thus be
> used with [`git diff`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-diff) to show the changes you've made so far to resolve
> conflicts.
> Using the same example as above, after resolving the conflict we
> get:
>
> ```bash
> $ git diff AUTO_MERGE
> diff --git a/file.txt b/file.txt
> index cd10406..8bf5ae7 100644
> --- a/file.txt
> b/file.txt
> @@ -1,5 +1 @@
> -<<<<<<< HEAD:file.txt
> -Hello world
> -=======
> -Goodbye
> ->>>>>>> 77976da35a11db4580b80ae27e8d65caf5208086:file.txt
> Goodbye world
> ```
>
> Notice that the diff shows we deleted the conflict markers and both versions of the content line, and wrote "`Goodbye world`" instead.

---

The [OP Max](https://stackoverflow.com/users/336184/max) adds in [the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76495313/replicate-intellij-merge-commit-details-functionality-in-cli-vanilla-git/76496753?noredirect=1#comment135121138_76496753):

> Actually I found out that `git merge-base` does *not* work properly when there were periodic merges into branch `B` from branch `A` before we finally merge `B` into `A`.
>
> So it seems we can't find "changes brought to `A` in a final merge of `B` to `A`" using `git merge-base` in a general case.

See "[Git: how to find commit hash where branch originated from](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3998883/6309#comment4283509_3999084)".

Comment: VonC, i ran `git merge-tree --write-tree --no-messages --name-only <rev>^1 <rev>^2` and i  see, it does indeed give me conflicted file. but also some SHA that i don't see in my Git commits log in IntellJ, what could that SHA be? some internal stuff not getting to final commits log?

Comment: @Max Not sure, which is why I mentioned the same command without `--name-only`: it can add conflict reasons.

Comment: ah, ok. i've never used `merge-tree`, maybe that is a sort of "dry run" merge, kind of "modelling" a real merge (?) - hense those "virtual" SHAs. i need to read more on it.

Comment: @Max True, I have edited the answer to make clear that `<rev>` here is the merge commit. By using `<rev>^1 <rev>^2`, you are forcing Git to "re-simulate" the merge between its two parents.

Comment: cool. i'll piggyback on your advanced git knowledge :) . imagine i want to explore situation that existed for person when he was resolving merge even more further... say, we have "merge base" commit sha=000, then last commit in branch1 before merge sha=111, and last commit in branch2 sha=222. i want to "simulate" the merge person was facing and see the combined changes (including conflicts) of that "virtual" merge. imagine smth similar to "git merge-tree --write-tree" but spitting kind of a diff to us...

Comment: @Max All you need are the parents of the merge commit. In your case, 111 and 222: `git merge-tree --write-tree --no-messages 111 222`. The "merge base" will be recomputed by Git while running that command.

Comment: well, yep. it does not show me the "diff" like output. imagine i want to replicate the situation existed for a person when he got a merge conflict (before he resolved the conflicts and made his historical merge commit)

Comment: imagine i want to sit "into time machine" and see the diff of conflicted merge the person was facing before he started to resolve conflict (+including not-conflicted well-merged files)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/254119/discussion-between-vonc-and-max).

Comment: actually i found out that `git merge-base` does not work properly when there were periodic merges into branch B from branch A before we finally merge B into A. So seems we can't find "changes brought to A in a final merge of B to A" using `git merge-base` in a general case... see more at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3998883/git-how-to-find-commit-hash-where-branch-originated-from#comment4283509_3999084

Comment: @Max Good catch. I will include your comment in the answer... [as soon as I am able to](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/425430/6309)

Comment: i've asked new question for people to reassure me in my findings - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76641205/what-a-git-merge-of-a-branch-has-brought-to-master

Comment: @Max I have ([finally!](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/425430/how-can-i-avoid-an-error-occurred-submitting-the-edit-error-message)) included your comment in the answer.