# How to make sure others people cannot edit my git notes?

Tags: git, readonly, git-notes

I want to make release notes by using git notes, but I am not sure if other people change my git notes by using the same ref.

BTW, `chmod 444 .git/refs/notes/abc_test` & `.git/logs/refs/notes/abc_test` does not work.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't think you really can protect published git notes.

What you can do is put them in an explicit [namespace](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5213110/6309), as mentioned [in here](http://lists-archives.com/git/714256-git-notes-usage.html):

> I think for "typical usage" one stores others' notes in a different place anyways, e.g. I store Thomas' list-notes in refs/remotes/trast/notes/ so that they don't interfer with my own notes.

If in the same namespace, then [they can be merged](http://vmiklos.hu/blog/git-notes-merge.html):

```
git checkout refs/notes/commits
git fetch origin refs/notes/commits
git merge FETCH_HEAD
git update-ref refs/notes/commits HEAD
git checkout master
```

But that would change their content.

Comment: Note: this script (http://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/15380/am-i-making-any-beginner-errors-in-the-bash-script-for-adding-trusted-timestamps) add some kind on verification on a `git notes` specific content, and acts as a wrapper to manipulate `git notes`.

Comment: Thank you for the quick response.

I can use git to make some repository read-only, why cannot make some of the git notes read-only...If the published git notes cannot be protected, is would be unsafe...

Comment: @Flyakite because once you have fetched those notes in your local repo, they are yours to modify and push back. If your remote repo has Gitoliote V3 though, then you could reject notes coming from anyone else than you with VREFS. See http://stackoverflow.com/a/10888358/6309

Comment: @Flyakite the read-only you are speaking of is on the repo level (all repo read-only). We are talking about specific part of a git repo, and git doesn't block natively a part of a repo: if you can push to a repo, you can push anything.

Answer (score 1):

This [Git man page](https://help.github.com/articles/remove-sensitive-data) details how to remove sensitive data and it states that you can

> add [the file] to the .gitignore to ensure it is not accidentally re-committed

I do not think that it is possible to have a file versioned, but not visible to others, due to the distributed model Git uses. Setting the file to read only will not have the desired effect once the file is copied to another user's repository.

Does that answer your question?

Comment: for a specific namespace of git notes, let's say xxx, which path should I add to .gitignore? Below does not work
$ cat .gitignore
/.git/refs/notes/xxx
/.git/logs/refs/notes/xxx

Comment: Have you tried leaving out the starting slash (/)? That points to the root of your file system after all and according to the [gitignore man page](http://git-scm.com/docs/gitignore) the filenames in a particular .gitignore file are relative to the location of that file. So as far as I understand you could also put a .gitignore in the directory that contains the notes. If you want to add an entire directory, let the pattern end with / do in your example you could punt a .gitignore file in the notes dir that contains "**xxx/**" (without the quotes).

Comment: sorry for the typo, `.git/refs/notes/xxx` it should be like this. .gitignore will ignore the files when `git add something`. while git notes do not need to commit it by hand, run git push origin refs/notes/xxx would make it. As a result, .gitignore might not help on this.

Answer (score 1):

In the same way you protect your own repository: don’t let anyone else
push to it.

But since you are asking this then it might be the case that you are
already in a shared repository. And while you can probably selectively
“protect” certain branches, you can (probably) not do the same for
specific refs like notes.

Then the only thing you can do is to make another (remote) repository
somewhere else and push the notes thataway. Then tell people that the
release notes are in another repository.