# Find merge commit for release branch

Tags: git

With the following git history:

```
            f---g---h--- feature
           /         \
      c---e---i---j---k---l--- release
     /                     \
-a--b---d---m---n---o---p---q---[hundreds of commits]--- master
```

I have the SHA of commit `g`. Neither feature, nor release are available any longer and I need to find commit `q`, IE where the release branch was merged into master. With the answers in a different question ([Find merge commit which include a specific commit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8475448/find-merge-commit-which-include-a-specific-commit)) I can only find commit k, where the feature branch was merged into the release branch. How do I go about this?

Comment: Saying you can't find `q` is a bit like saying you can't find `master`, which is possible but a bit hard to believe.

Comment: @JB. You're right, I updated the question. There are a lot of commits after `q`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the feature or release branches had unique names you should be able to find `q` on `master` by searching its merge commits for that unique name (e.g. by using `gitk --merges` and then entering a term in the `Find` field) because Git by default records the merged branch names in merge commit messages.

Otherwise, you could just search for the first merge commit on `master`that has `g` merged with a script similar to this one:

```
g=ad198bc
for i in $(git log --merges --reverse --format=%H); do
    revlist=$(git rev-list -1 $g --not $i)
    if [ $? -eq 0 ]; then
        if [ "$revlist" = "" ]; then
            echo "Merge commit $i has $g merged."
            exit
        fi
    fi
done
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you're Git history looks exactly as you have described:

```
            f---g---h--- feature
           /         \
      c---e---i---j---k---l--- release
     /                     \
-a--b---d---m---n---o---p---q---[hundreds of commits]--- master
```

Then one way you can find `q` is simply by examining your `git log`. Use

```
git log --oneline --graph
```

then in the `less` pager output (I'm assuming that you're using `less` as your pager), hit `/` and then type the sha for `g`, which will then cause `less` to search the `git log` output for that sha. Then simply scroll up a little in the output until you find `q`.

Comment: Unfortunately this wouldn't work in practice since there are also a huge amount of commits between `k` and `l`.

Answer (score -1):

I would suggest this:

```
git log --merges --ancestry-path g..q
```

`--merges` logs only merge commits, and `--ancestry-path` limits the commits to only those on the path between g and q. In this case it should show you both k and q.

Comment: The original poster doesn't know `q` though.

Comment: Well, it doesn't have to be `q` - it could be anything later on, like `HEAD` or `master`, or whatever...