# Find the merge commit that modified a given line?

Tags: git, merge, pull-request

We're using a git-flow style workflow, and we want to find out which pull request included changes to a given line of code.

Suppose we have the following history:

```
       c---e---g
      /         \
-a---b---d---f---h--- master
```

My pull request was merged in `h` with commit message "Merge pull request #123".

If I do a git blame on the lines of code added in the pull request, it shows me `e`, rather than `h`.

```
12345678 (Wilfred Hughes           2015-02-02 15:22:40 +0000 402) # Some old code
e        (Wilfred Hughes           2015-02-12 15:22:40 +0000 402) # Added in the PR, line 1
e        (Wilfred Hughes           2015-02-12 15:22:40 +0000 403) # Added in the PR, line 2
56789012 (Wilfred Hughes           2015-02-26 17:24:18 +0000 404) # More old code
```

How can I find the merge commit for a given line of code in git?

(Note this is different from [this related question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8475448/509706) as I'm starting with lines of code, not commits).

Comment: Have you tried `git log --reverse --merges --topo-order <commit-e>..`? The first entry should correspond to commit `h`.

Comment: you could use this question http://stackoverflow.com/q/8475448/2082964 : how to find the merge following a certain commit

Answer (score 3):

A merge-commit would only appear in git-blame if you had resolved conflict in that commit.

For normal merges without conflict, *h* would never appear in git blame as it did not change in any line of code and merely merged *g* and *f*.

So what you want can be achieved in 2 phases

1. First find which commit impacted line of code you are interested in. This can be achieved via git blame -L option ( comes in git 1.8.4). Give a range of 10+ lines as it is likely exact line number might have changed.

   *$ git blame -L200,+10 -- filename.ext*
2. Find the first merge commit following the commit found in step 1
   So you would have to first find which commit impacted the line of code you are interested in. This can be achieved as answered in [Find merge commit which include a specific commit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8475448/find-merge-commit-which-include-a-specific-commit)