# Seeking explanation of Magic Perl Shared Lines Oneliner

Tags: perl

I found this ([here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10079510/340947) if you must know), and it caught my attention.

```
$ perl -ne 'print if ($seen{$_} .= @ARGV) =~ /10$/' file1 file2
```

I do know perl. But I do not know how this does what it does.

```
$ perl -ne 'print if ($seen{$_} .= @ARGV) =~ /10$/' <(echo 'zz\nabc\n3535\ndef') <(echo 'abc\ndef\nff')
abc
def
```

Seems like it just spits out the lines of the input files that are shared. Now putting every line into a hash as key, or something, I can see how it can help achieve that task, but... What the hell is going on with that regex?

Thinking about it some more, nothing about the use of `.=` is obvious either.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

- The expression `$seen{$_} .= @ARGV` appends the number of elements in `@ARGV` to `$seen{$_}`
- While the first file is being read, `@ARGV` contains only one element -- the second file name
- While the second file is being read, `@ARGV` is empty
- The value of `$_`, which is used as the key for the `%seen` hash, is the latest line read from either file
- If any given line appears only in the first file, only a `1` will be appended to the hash element
- If any given line appears only in the second file, only a `0` will be appended to the hash element
- If any given line appears in both files, a `1` and then a `0` will be appended to the hash element, leaving it set to `10`
- When reading through the second file, if the appended `0` character results in a value of `10` then the line is printed
- This results in all lines that appear in *both* files being printed to the output

Comment: OK.. so this (one of the many items here) i wasnt aware of... If the program is one line, then it is used as a line filter on each arg (reading each arg in succession)? So essentially we have a doubly nested loop. All implicit. Wow.

Comment: @StevenLu: The `-n` option executes the code for every line read from the input files. It's only a singly-nested loop as the files are read in sequence as if they are concatenated. Perl shifts another file name off `@ARGV` and opens it each time it needs more data

Comment: Oh ok i missed the significance of the `-n` flag. It's less astonishing now.