# How to find the oldest common descendant of two commits in git?

Tags: git, git-merge, git-rev-list

Given two (or more) commits, I want to find the oldest merge which joins them. Something like the opposite of `git merge-base` (which finds the youngest common ancestors). Notice that the commit I’m looking for will be a younger descendant of the starting commits.

In other words: I want to investigate the merge commit which merged two given commits (where changes to the same file happened).

Comment: Isn't it what you want? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8475448/find-merge-commit-which-include-a-specific-commit

Comment: @smyatkin_max No, that question has a branch given, where the merge should be on. (I don’t know yet which branch has the oldest merge commit I’m looking for.)

Answer (score 1):

```
oldest-merge() { 
        ( for c; do git log --all --merges --ancestry-path ^$c --pretty='%aI %h %s'; done ) \
        | sort | uniq -c | awk "\$1 == $# {print;exit}"
}

oldest-merge `git rev-list --all --grep=BUG-27182`  # e.g.
```

the final awk takes the first commit that showed up in all the merge-ancestry lists.

Comment: The output is given in reverse chronological order by default.

Answer (score 0):

If $a and $b are the two commit hashes and they are both contained in master, then say

```
git rev-list $a..master --ancestry-path >a
git rev-list $b..master --ancestry-path >b
```

Then use a diff tool to find the last common line of a an b.

Comment: I've tried this and when using `cmp` for comparison, I do find a common commit. However this is not the "earliest"/"oldest" common commit that has both `a` and `b` commit's changes. It's not even the "latest"/"youngest" commit either. It's somewhere in between. Not entirely sure.