# Git Log = display the merged revision id from an specific revision

Tags: git, logging

Given the revision id - how would i get the merged revision id.

For example:

```
0ea6c61 username Fri Sep 9 15:41:44 2016 +0800 Merged in deployment (pull request #90) (a9315f2 037ebce) 
037ebce username Fri Sep 9 15:32:08 2016 +0800 remove comment, missed deployment (a85b748)
```

How can I get using a git log command to display the merged "0ea6c61" using "037ebce" as my filter.

Is there some kind of filter like git log -get-merged-id=037ebce, and using that it would display the merged id. So my expectation on that sample command is it would display below since that's the merged for that revision.

```
0ea6c61 username Fri Sep 9 15:41:44 2016 +0800 Merged in deployment (pull request #90) (a9315f2 037ebce)
```

Comment: Check out this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8475448/find-merge-commit-which-include-a-specific-commit

Answer (score 0):

Wouldn't some variation of

```
git log --merges |grep -E -B1 'Merge:.+037ebce'
```

Work ?

You might also be interested in a tool like [this one](https://github.com/mhagger/git-when-merged)