# How to checkout remote branch git?

Tags: git, github, git-checkout

Me and my team member are working on same repository. Someone create a branch from master called test_01, worked on that and commit, push to test_01 and merge to master. In the meantime some commit are done in master. Now I want to checkout that test_01 so that I write

```
 git checkout test_01
```

and got a git error : pathspec 'test_01' did not match any file know to git .

Comment: Check if test_01 is still pesent in git, if not you can restore this branch.

Comment: It exist in remote repository , But dont have this branch in local

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I check out a remote Git branch?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1783405/how-do-i-check-out-a-remote-git-branch)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

After a `git fetch`, check the list of the remote tracking branches with:

```
git branch -avv
```

If you see `origin/test_01`, a `git checkout test_01` should work, since it is the equivalent of:

```
git checkout -b <branch> --track <remote>/<branch>
```

Or, since [Git 2.23+, Q3 2019](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57066202/6309):

```
git switch <branch>
```

(through its "[guess mode](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-switch#Documentation/git-switch.txt---guess)", that will be the same as `git switch -c <branch> --track <remote>/<branch>`)

But since it does not work, it is likely the `test_01` branch was merged to `master` locally by the other developer, and only `master` was pushed.

You can try and look for the commit of that unnamed branch merged into `master`: see "[Find merge commit which include a specific commit](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8475448/6309)".

Comment: Thanks, this worked for me, but the initial `fetch` was the secret, otherwise you get the `did not match any file` error.  Once you do the `fetch`, though, you're able to checkout the branch with the proper tracking as you indicated.

Comment: this is how's done ... and like someone said, adding `git fetch` as the first statement, rounds this out to nicely!  thank you @vonc!