# Find merge commit that introduced certain changes to current branch

Tags: git

Consider the following history:

```
         c-----f-----i-----l-----o-----p--- branch2
        /           /                   \
       /   e---h---k---n--- branch1      \
      /   /                               \
-a---b---d---g---j---m---------------------q---r--- master
```

The commit `h` (branch1) introduced certain changes to a piece of code. At some point in history after `h`, branch1 was merged into branch2. After a few more commits, branch2 was merged into master.

I want to find the merge commit that introduced the changes made in commit `h` to master branch (here merge commit `q`)?
I have the commit hash for `h`.

I tried the solutions given here: [Find merge commit which include a specific commit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8475448/find-merge-commit-which-include-a-specific-commit) , but they point to the first merge commit after the commit `h` which is `i`.

Comment: @Quentin, Looks Vivek already tried the answers on the question which you mentioned.

Comment: @GanesaVijayakumar oh god, how have I brainfarted *this* bad? Retracting my VTC, thanks for pointing that out...

Comment: Aside from things like `git log -S` (for which you'd have to use `-m` as well), you can also use graph ancestry tests (`git merge-base --is-ancestor`) on each of the legs of a merge. In this case there's a single unique merge `q` that makes `h` an ancestor of `q` and `p` but not of `m`, so `git log --merges` (or `git rev-list --merges`) to find merges followed by said merge-base testing would get you there.

Comment: In a more complex graph, however, there may be multiple ways to trace from `r` back to `h`. In this case, you might want the equivalent of `git merge-base`'s "best" commit. That's more complicated to test for, and in particularly nasty DAGs, there may not even be a single best such merge.

Comment: Seems like there is no out of the box solution for this. For the particular graph that I posted, @torek 's solution from his first comment worked, thanks!! However, like he mentioned in his second comment, my actual graph is much more complex and I was not able to get to where I wanted.