# Git: What branch a commit originated from

Tags: git

From what I've seen the outlook seems pretty bleak, but just in case here are my requirements:

1. Determine which branch a given commit originated in.
2. Determine which commits originated in a given branch.

From what I've read both of these scenarios seem kind of impossible, doubly so after the branch in question has been merged into master.

Comment: It's likely somewhat doable depending on *how* the branches were merged back in. If there is a merge commit (i.e., merges were done with `--no-ff`), you at least have a merge commit to go by.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Git: Finding what branch a commit came from](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2706797/git-finding-what-branch-a-commit-came-from)

Comment: Note that very often, when you ask this question, you're actually trying to accomplish something else, and you don't actually need to do it this way. Git branches are meant to be lightweight and often transient. Consider for example `git log --merges --ancestry-path <commit>..master`. You probably care about the merge commit (and maybe who merged it), and not necessarily the name of the branch it was on when it was merged.

Comment: @Jefromi: I'm actually trying to accomplish two things, both related by the fact that they require determining the relationship between commits and the branches they originated from: 1) For auditing purposes it seems impossible to determine (once merged into master) that a commit was done in a branch by a developer then merged into master later by a team lead. 2) It would be nice in our issue tracker to be able to supply a branch name to a ticket and be able to see which commits were done under that branch in the ticket.

Answer (score 0):

You might want try this script: https://github.com/SethRobertson/git-what-branch

```
EXAMPLES
     # git-what-branch --all 1f9c381fa3e0b9b9042e310c69df87eaf9b46ea4
     v2.6.12-rc3-450-g1f9c381 used the following minimal temporal path:
       merged to v2.6.12-rc3-461-g84e48b6 @Tue May  3 18:27:24 2005
       merged to v2.6.12-rc3-590-gbfd4bda @Thu May  5 08:59:37 2005
       v2.6.12-rc3-590-gbfd4bda is on v2.6.12-n
       v2.6.12-rc3-590-gbfd4bda is on v2.6.12-rc4-n
       [...]
       v2.6.12-rc3-590-gbfd4bda is on v2.6.36-rc4-n
       v2.6.12-rc3-590-gbfd4bda is on v2.6.36-rc5-n(aka master)
```