# Git log to get commits only for a specific branch

Tags: git

I want to list all commits that are only part of a specific branch.

With the following, it lists all the commits from the branch, but also from the parent (master)

```
git log mybranch
```

The other option I found, was to exclude the commits reachable by master and gives me what I want, BUT I would like to avoid the need of knowing the other branches names.

```
git log mybranch --not master
```

I was trying to use `git for-each-ref`, but it is also listing mybranch so actually it is excluding all:

```
git log mybranch --not $(git for-each-ref --format '^%(refname:short)' refs/heads/)
```

**Update:**

I'm testing a new option that I found a while ago, and till now seems that this could be what I was looking for:

```
git log --walk-reflogs mybranch
```

**Update (2013-02-13T15:08):**

The --walk-reflogs option is good, but I checked that there is an expiration for reflogs (default 90 days, [gc.reflogExpire](http://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-gc.html)).

I think I found the answer I was looking for:

```
git log mybranch --not $(git for-each-ref --format='%(refname)' refs/heads/ | grep -v "refs/heads/mybranch")
```

I'm just removing the current branch from list of branches available and using that list to be excluded from the log. This way I only get the commits that are **only reached by mybranch**.

Comment: possible duplicate with http://stackoverflow.com/questions/53569

Comment: Already saw that question also, but not the same

Comment: Are you sure that's what you want?  I find it better to have a target in mind: "what's on my branch that's not in the upstream", or "what's on my branch that's not in master".  Plus, while git is fast at pruning, this is going to get more expensive as you have more branches.  I have a script I use which I call "git missing" after bzr's "missing" command.  You can find it here: https://github.com/jszakmeister/etc/blob/master/git-addons/git-missing.

Comment: I actually need this for a post-receive hook, so "master" wont be always the branch to exclude

Comment: Yes, the duplicate mentioned by StarPinkER worked well for me:git log $(git merge-base HEAD branch)..branch

Answer (score 303):

From what it sounds like you should be using `cherry`:

```
git cherry -v develop mybranch
```

This would show all of the commits which are contained within *mybranch*, but NOT in *develop*. If you leave off the last option (*mybranch*), it will compare the current branch instead.

As VonC pointed out, you are ALWAYS comparing your branch to another branch, so know your branches and then choose which one to compare to.

Comment: This is exactly what I needed, but it seems like there should be a more intuitive command (yes even in the world of Git) for this.

Comment: You can also do `git cherry -v master` to compare your current branch with the master branch.

Comment: The danger in using git cherry, is that commits are only matched if their file diffs are identical between branches.  If any sort of merging was done which would make the diffs different between one branch, and the other, then git cherry sees them as different commits.

Comment: This just gives me `fatal: Unknown commit mybranch`.

Comment: @MattArnold you have to change the text "develop" and "mybranch" to branches which exist on your repo

Comment: I don't understand why this get upvoted when OP explicitly said he wants to avoid to name another branch explicitly. And `git cherry -v develop mybranch` is very similar to `git log mybranch --not develop` that OP mentions.

Answer (score 54):

> BUT I would like to avoid the need of knowing the other branches names.

I don't think this is possible: a branch in Git is always based on another one or at least on another commit, as explained in "[git diff doesn't show enough](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5256249/git-diff-doesnt-show-enough/5257065#5257065)":

[image]

You need a reference point for your log to show the right commits.

As mentioned in "[GIT - Where did I branch from?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9898093/git-where-did-i-branch-from)":

> branches are simply pointers to certain commits in a DAG

So even if `git log master..mybranch` is one answer, it would still show too many commits, if `mybranch` is based on `myotherbranch`, itself based on `master`.

In order to find that reference (the origin of your branch), you can only parse commits and see in which branch they are, as seen in:

- "[Git: Finding what branch a commit came from](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2707110/6309)".
- "[How can I see what branch another branch was forked from?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4803492/how-can-i-see-what-branch-another-branch-was-forked-from)"

Answer (score 42):

I finally found the way to do what the OP wanted. It's as simple as:

```
git log --graph [branchname] 

git log --graph origin/[branchname] # if your local checkout isn't up to date
```

The command will display all commits that are reachable from the provided branch in the format of graph. But, you can easily filter all commits on that branch by looking at the commits graph whose `*` is the first character in the commit line.

For example, let's look at the excerpt of `git log --graph master` on cakephp GitHub repo below:

```
D:\Web Folder\cakephp>git log --graph master
*   commit 8314c2ff833280bbc7102cb6d4fcf62240cd3ac4
|\  Merge: c3f45e8 0459a35
| | Author: José Lorenzo Rodríguez <lorenzo@users.noreply.github.com>
| | Date:   Tue Aug 30 08:01:59 2016 +0200
| |
| |     Merge pull request #9367 from cakephp/fewer-allocations
| |
| |     Do fewer allocations for simple default values.
| |
| * commit 0459a35689fec80bd8dca41e31d244a126d9e15e
| | Author: Mark Story <mark@mark-story.com>
| | Date:   Mon Aug 29 22:21:16 2016 -0400
| |
| |     The action should only be defaulted when there are no patterns
| |
| |     Only default the action name when there is no default & no pattern
| |     defined.
| |
| * commit 80c123b9dbd1c1b3301ec1270adc6c07824aeb5c
| | Author: Mark Story <mark@mark-story.com>
| | Date:   Sun Aug 28 22:35:20 2016 -0400
| |
| |     Do fewer allocations for simple default values.
| |
| |     Don't allocate arrays when we are only assigning a single array key
| |     value.
| |
* |   commit c3f45e811e4b49fe27624b57c3eb8f4721a4323b
|\ \  Merge: 10e5734 43178fd
| |/  Author: Mark Story <mark@mark-story.com>
|/|   Date:   Mon Aug 29 22:15:30 2016 -0400
| |
| |       Merge pull request #9322 from cakephp/add-email-assertions
| |
| |       Add email assertions trait
| |
| * commit 43178fd55d7ef9a42706279fa275bb783063cf34
| | Author: Jad Bitar <jadbitar@mac.com>
| | Date:   Mon Aug 29 17:43:29 2016 -0400
| |
| |     Fix `@since` in new files docblocks
| |
```

As you can see, only commits `8314c2ff833280bbc7102cb6d4fcf62240cd3ac4` and `c3f45e811e4b49fe27624b57c3eb8f4721a4323b` have the `*` being the first character in the commit lines. Those commits are from the master branch while the other four are from some other branches.

Comment: This isn't the same thing, but gets the job done for a small number of commits.

Comment: Yes, my ugly solution is something similar. I'd do something like `git log --oneline --graph | grep '^*'`, where the `graph` decorates all lines according to their branch (sort of), and `grep` selects all lines with a certain decoration. In this case I'll get only the current branch. To make this work you need to get the grep regexp right for your needs.

Answer (score 25):

I'm using the following commands:

```
git shortlog --no-merges --graph --abbrev-commit master..<mybranch>
```

or

```
git log --no-merges --oneline --decorate master..<mybranch>
```

Comment: +1. `--graph` only adds `*` as first character, so this option can be avoided. `--abbrev-comit` and `--decorate` seems to make no difference (for my branches).

Answer (score 16):

The following shell command should do what you want:

```sh
git log --all --not $(git rev-list --no-walk --exclude=refs/heads/mybranch --all)
```

#### Caveats

If you have `mybranch` checked out, the above command won't work.  That's because the commits on `mybranch` are also reachable by `HEAD`, so Git doesn't consider the commits to be unique to `mybranch`.  To get it to work when `mybranch` is checked out, you must also add an exclude for `HEAD`:

```sh
git log --all --not $(git rev-list --no-walk \
    --exclude=refs/heads/mybranch \
    --exclude=HEAD \
    --all)
```

However, you should *not* exclude `HEAD` unless the `mybranch` is checked out, otherwise you risk showing commits that are not exclusive to `mybranch`.

Similarly, if you have a remote branch named `origin/mybranch` that corresponds to the local `mybranch` branch, you'll have to exclude it:

```sh
git log --all --not $(git rev-list --no-walk \
    --exclude=refs/heads/mybranch \
    --exclude=refs/remotes/origin/mybranch \
    --all)
```

And if the remote branch is the default branch for the remote repository (usually only true for `origin/master`), you'll have to exclude `origin/HEAD` as well:

```sh
git log --all --not $(git rev-list --no-walk \
    --exclude=refs/heads/mybranch \
    --exclude=refs/remotes/origin/mybranch \
    --exclude=refs/remotes/origin/HEAD \
    --all)
```

If you have the branch checked out, *and* there's a remote branch, *and* the remote branch is the default for the remote repository, then you end up excluding a lot:

```sh
git log --all --not $(git rev-list --no-walk \
    --exclude=refs/heads/mybranch \
    --exclude=HEAD
    --exclude=refs/remotes/origin/mybranch \
    --exclude=refs/remotes/origin/HEAD \
    --all)
```

#### Explanation

The `git rev-list` command is a low-level (plumbing) command that walks the given revisions and dumps the SHA1 identifiers encountered.  Think of it as equivalent to `git log` except it only shows the SHA1—no log message, no author name, no timestamp, none of that "fancy" stuff.

The `--no-walk` option, as the name implies, prevents `git rev-list` from walking the ancestry chain.  So if you type `git rev-list --no-walk mybranch` it will only print one SHA1 identifier:  the identifier of the tip commit of the `mybranch` branch.

The `--exclude=refs/heads/mybranch --all` arguments tell `git rev-list` to start from each reference except for `refs/heads/mybranch`.

So, when you run `git rev-list --no-walk --exclude=refs/heads/mybranch --all`, Git prints the SHA1 identifier of the tip commit of each ref except for `refs/heads/mybranch`.  These commits and their ancestors are the commits you are *not* interested in—these are the commits you do *not* want to see.

The *other* commits are the ones you want to see, so we collect the output of `git rev-list --no-walk --exclude=refs/heads/mybranch --all` and tell Git to show everything but those commits and their ancestors.

The `--no-walk` argument is necessary for large repositories (and is an optimization for small repositories):  Without it, Git would have to print, and the shell would have to collect (and store in memory) many more commit identifiers than necessary.  With a large repository, the number of collected commits could easily exceed the shell's command-line argument limit.

#### Git bug?

I would have expected the following to work:

```sh
git log --all --not --exclude=refs/heads/mybranch --all
```

but it does not.  I'm guessing this is a bug in Git, but maybe it's intentional.

Comment: I came here wanting to know how to do Mercurial's `hg log -b <branch>`. I don't understand why people say git is unfriendly. /s

Comment: I don't know why `git log --all --not --exclude=refs/heads/mybranch --all` doesn't work but `git log refs/heads/mybranch --not --exclude=refs/heads/mybranch --all` does, with the same caveats about excluding HEAD and origin.

Comment: This is the best and only real answer to all similar "this-branch-only" questions on SO. The issue about excluding `HEAD` or not can be fixed if one is ok to ignore tags, using `git log --branches --remotes --not $(git rev-list --no-walk --exclude=mybranch --branches --remotes)`. Note the different ref syntax for `exclude` here.

Comment: ...  Or using @BenC solution: `git log mybranch --not --exclude=mybranch --branches --remotes`, which is quite compact.

Answer (score 15):

**Fast answer:**

```
git log $(git merge-base master b2)..HEAD
```

**Let's say:**

1. That you have a **master** branch
2. Do a few commits
3. You created a branch named **b2**
4. Do `git log -n1`; the commit Id is the merge base between b2 and master
5. Do a few commits in **b2**
6. `git log` will show your log history of b2 and master
7. Use commit range, if you aren't familiar with the concept, I invite you to google it or stack overflow-it,

   For your actual context, you can do for example

   ```
   git log commitID_FOO..comitID_BAR
   ```

   The ".." is the range operator for the log command.

   That mean, in a simple form, give me all logs more recent than commitID_FOO...
8. Look at point #4, the merge base

   So: `git log COMMITID_mergeBASE..HEAD` will show you the difference
9. Git can retrieve the merge base for you like this

   ```
   git merge-base b2 master
   ```
10. Finally you can do:

    ```
    git log $(git merge-base master b2)..HEAD
    ```

Answer (score 5):

You could try something like this:

```
#!/bin/bash

all_but()
{
    target="$(git rev-parse $1)"
    echo "$target --not"
    git for-each-ref --shell --format="ref=%(refname)" refs/heads | \
    while read entry
    do
        eval "$entry"

        test "$ref" != "$target" && echo "$ref"
    done
}

git log $(all_but $1)
```

Or, borrowing from the [recipe in the Git User's Manual](http://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/user-manual.html#showing-commits-unique-to-a-branch):

```
#!/bin/bash
git log $1 --not $( git show-ref --heads | cut -d' ' -f2 | grep -v "^$1" )
```

Comment: +1. I was writing in my answer that you need to parse commits in order to find the origin of your branch, and you seem to have done just that.

Comment: Have you used log --walk-reflogs? I'm reading about this option and is is giving me the results i need till now, (still testing)

Comment: @dimirc Reflogs are a different beast all together.  It records branch points over time, generally for the purpose of recovery.  I'm not sure what you're doing in your post-receive hook but maybe if you explained it, folks could provide a more sensible answer to your problem.

Comment: I just need to parse/check all the commit messages at a push. The case I want to cover is if someone pushes multiple commits at master and creates a new branch with multiple commits too. The post-receive hook need to check the changes done for both refs/branches, for example master and newbranch, I need to know the bounderies for the new branch to avoid parsing commit messages twice, since could be commit from master.

Comment: Okay.  Then I think the above approach I outlined really is what you want.  With reflog, entries are going to fall off after some period of time, and I think that will cause you some headaches.  You might want to look at using `git show-ref --tags` too.

Comment: @jszakmeister Yes, reglog (30 days default) but what do you think about >> git log mybranch --not $(git for-each-ref --format='%(refname)' refs/heads/ | grep -v "refs/heads/mybranch") I updated my question a couple of hours ago including this details

Comment: @dimirc that's essentially what the script I presented above does. :-)

Comment: This did not for me (tried with $1 = trunk/master and dev_branch), it showed commits that already existed in master. Frederic Nault's answer did work. 
`git checkout dev_branch && git log $(git merge-base trunk/master dev_branch)..HEAD`

Comment: @kevinf I don't think you need the merge-base invocation there.  `git log master..` should do the trick for you.

Answer (score 4):

This will output the commits on the current branch. If any argument is passed, it just outputs the hashes.

## git_show_all_commits_only_on_this_branch

```
#!/bin/bash
function show_help()
{
  ME=$(basename $0)
  IT=$(cat <<EOF
  
  usage: $ME {NEWER_BRANCH} {OLDER_BRANCH} {VERBOSE}
  
  Compares 2 different branches, and lists the commits found only 
  in the first branch (newest branch). 

  e.g. 
  
  $ME         -> default. compares current branch to master
  $ME B1      -> compares branch B1 to master
  $ME B1 B2   -> compares branch B1 to B2
  $ME B1 B2 V -> compares branch B1 to B2, and displays commit messages
  
  )
  echo "$IT"
  exit
}

if [ "$1" == "help" ]
then
  show_help
fi

# Show commit msgs if any arg passed for arg 3
if [ "$3" ]
then
  OPT="-v"
fi

# get branch names
OLDER_BRANCH=${2:-"master"}
if [ -z "$1" ]
then
  NEWER_BRANCH=$(git rev-parse --abbrev-ref HEAD)
else
  NEWER_BRANCH=$1
fi

if [ "$NEWER_BRANCH" == "$OLDER_BRANCH" ]
then
  echo "  Please supply 2 different branches to compare!"
  show_help
fi

OUT=$(\git cherry $OPT $OLDER_BRANCH $NEWER_BRANCH)

if [ -z "$OUT" ]
then
  echo "No differences found. The branches $NEWER_BRANCH and $OLDER_BRANCH are in sync."
  exit;
fi

if [ "$OPT" == "-v" ]
then
  echo "$OUT"
else
  echo "$OUT" | awk '{print $2}'
fi
```

Comment: This produced about 100 irrelevant log messages for me.

Comment: Hey @ArlieStephens - I tried it and it seemed to work for me still? I just added help and more error messages to the above. Let me know how it goes!

Comment: Interesting. Looking at the code as you have it now, I think it may be as simple as the original assuming that the branch I care about came off of master. With the current code, I could have specified the parent branch explicitly. (IIRC, my dev branch came from a release branch, not master.)

Comment: @ArlieStephens - yeah I don't think I changed any functionality.... I updated it one more time and made the docs a bit more exact after some local testing... and added a "verbose" option that was there before, but I didnt doc it

Answer (score 4):

I found this approach relatively easy.

Checkout to the branch and than

1. Run

   ```
   git rev-list --simplify-by-decoration -2 HEAD
   ```

This will provide just two SHAs:

1) last commit of the branch [C1]

2) and commit parent to the first commit of the branch [C2]

2. Now run

   ```
   git log --decorate --pretty=oneline --reverse --name-status <C2>..<C1>
   ```

Here C1 and C2 are two strings you will get when you run first command. Put these values without <> in second command.

This will give list of history of file changing within the branch.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the suggestion but I followed the instructions exactly and the output was from the very beginning of the repo in 2015, whereas my work was 2022. Anyone else get it to work?

Answer (score 4):

```
git rev-list --exclude=master --branches --no-walk
```

will list the tips of every branch that isn't `master`.

```
git rev-list master --not $(git rev-list --exclude=master --branches --no-walk)
```

will list every commit in `master`'s history that's not in any other branch's history.

Sequencing is important for the options that set up the filter pipeline for commit selection, so `--branches` has to follow any exclusion patterns it's supposed to apply, and `--no-walk` has to follow the filters supplying commits rev-list isn't supposed to walk.

Answer (score 3):

Here I present an alias based on Richard Hansen's answer (and Ben C's suggestion), but that I adapted to exclude tags. The alias should be fairly robust.

```sh
# For Git 1.22+
git config --global alias.only '!b=${1:-$(git branch --show-current)}; git log --oneline --graph "heads/$b" --not --exclude="$b" --branches --remotes #'
# For older Git:
git config --global alias.only '!b=${1:-$(git symbolic-ref -q --short HEAD)}; b=${b##heads/}; git log --oneline --graph "heads/$b" --not --exclude="$b" --branches --remotes #'
```

Example of use:

```sh
git only mybranch  # Show commits that are in mybranch ONLY
git only           # Show commits that are ONLY in current branch
```

Note that **ONLY** means commits that would be **LOST** (after garbage collection) if the given branch was deleted (excluding the effect of tags). The alias should work even if there is unfortunately a tag named `mybranch` (thanks to prefix `heads/`). Note also that no commits are shown if they are part of any remote branch (including upstream if any), in compliance with the definition of *ONLY*.

The alias shows the one-line history as a graph of the selected commits.

```
  a --- b --- c --- master
   \           \
    \           d
     \           \
      e --- f --- g --- mybranch (HEAD)
       \
        h --- origin/other
```

With example above, `git only` would show:

```
  * (mybranch,HEAD)
  * g
  |\
  | * d
  * f
```

In order to include tags (but still excluding `HEAD`), the alias becomes (adapt as above for older Git):

```sh
git config --global alias.only '!b=${1:-$(git branch --show-current)};  git log --oneline --graph --all --not --exclude="refs/heads/$b" --exclude=HEAD --all #'
```

Or the variant that includes all the tags including HEAD (and removing current branch as default since it won't output anything):

```sh
git config --global alias.only '!git log --oneline --graph --all --not --exclude=\"refs/heads/$1\" --all #'
```

This last version is the only one that really satisfies the criteria commits-that-are-lost-if-given-branch-is-deleted, since a branch cannot be deleted if it is checked out, and no commit pointed by HEAD or any other tag will be lost. However the first two variants are more useful.

Finally, the alias does not work with remote branches (eg. `git only origin/master`). The alias must be modified, for instance:

```sh
git config --global alias.remote-only '!git log --oneline --graph "$1" --not --exclude="$1" --remotes --branches #'
```

Answer (score 2):

**Option 1** (seems faster but you may get the error `bash: /mingw64/bin/git: Argument list too long` in Git Bash (it worked in Linux though) depending on how many branches your project has)

`git log <your_branch> --not $(git branch -a | grep -v <your_branch> | grep -ve '->' | sed "s/\s//g")`

**Option 2**

`git rev-list <your_branch> | git name-rev --stdin | sed -E 's/~[0-9]+//g; s/\^[0-9]+//g' | grep " <your_branch>" | awk -F " " '{print $1}'`

Answer (score 1):

In my situation, we are using Git Flow and GitHub. All you need to do this is: Compare your feature branch with your develop branch on GitHub.

It will show the commits only made to your feature branch.

For example:

https://github.com/your_repo/compare/develop...feature_branch_name

Comment: I agree that when you get into the situation "I want to see what a pull request will look like", the best solution is often to ignore `git` and instead use GitHub to just make a pull request or compare the branches.

Answer (score 1):

I needed to export log in one line for a specific branch.

So I probably came out with a simpler solution.
When doing `git log --pretty=oneline --graph` we can see that all commit not done in the current branch are lines starting with `|`

So a simple `grep -v` do the job:
`git log --pretty=oneline --graph | grep -v "^|"`

Of course you can change the pretty parameter if you need other info, as soon as you keep it in one line.

You probably want to remove merge commit too.
As the message start with "Merge branch", pipe another `grep -v` and you're done.

In my specific ase, the final command was:
`git log --pretty="%ad : %an, %s" --graph | grep -v "^|" | grep -v "Merge branch"`

Answer (score 1):

This still was discussed in 2021 and the question was asked 8 years ago. I am puzzled why nobody is suggesting git --first-parent. Isn't that the solution nowadays? I currently have the same problem and this looks quite fine to me. I combined those options:

```
git --first-parent --cherry  first-commit-on-branch..
```

I even merged further commits from master into my feature branch, but those commits are filtered out because of cherry which is a combination of --cherry-pick, --right-only and --no-merges.
You manually need to find out the first commit on your branch or a commit from then on you want to find all following commits.

Answer (score 1):

From the above comments what I see that - you want only those commits belong to that branch only not to its parent. But technically if you think - when you create a branch from an another branch those commits also copy to the child branch.
But for your question the following commands will work.

```
git log childBranch...parentBranch
```

if the parent branch is a remote branch you can use the following command.

```
git log yourBranch --not --remotes=origin
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for the suggestion but it simply showed seemingly commits from all branches, going way far back past my branch’s creation. Did anyone get this approach working?

Answer (score 0):

I manage to do it by using `git log <branch>`
There is also an option to `--not <branch-name>`
original documentation : [git-log](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-log)

**example with format:**

```
git log branch-name  --date-order --format='%ai %an <%ae> %h %f'--format='%ai , %an ,<%ae> ,%h ,%f' >> c:\log.csv
```

Answer (score 0):

I made an alias to be able to simply type "git logbranch" and have all of the commits specific to your current branch.
Here is the alias:

```
[alias]
    logbranch = "!cd -- \"${GIT_PREFIX:-.}\" && CURRENT_BRANCH=$(git branch --show-current) && git log $CURRENT_BRANCH --not $(git for-each-ref --format='%(refname)' refs/heads/ | grep -v refs/heads/$CURRENT_BRANCH) #"
```

NB: Put that under the [alias] tag in the .gitconfig file, located in your home directory.

So, I basically used what has been originally posted in the [question post](https://stackoverflow.com/q/14848274/19618488) and used the CURRENT_BRANCH variable to make it quicker.
Hope this will save you some time!

Answer (score 0):

<strike>This works:</strike> This does exactly what you asked:

```
for a in $(git rev-list anybranch..mybranch); do echo -n "$a "; git branch --contains $a | xargs; done
```

You could use a draconian `git rev-list --all` but if you only care about commits on a branch not somewhere else, choosing any branch you think you came from will at least limit the actual distinct differences and you can see at a glance which commit(s) only belong to that branch.

Answer (score 0):

`git log --pretty=format:"%h"  --first-parent -n 20 <branch>`

this would return the 20 latest commits on the branch `<branch>`

- `--first-parent` will hide the commits coming from other merged
  branches
- `--pretty=format:"%h"` to show only the commit-id

---

from the documentation: https://git-scm.com/docs/git-log

```
--first-parent
When finding commits to include, follow only the first parent commit upon seeing a merge commit. This option can give a better overview when viewing the evolution of a particular topic branch, because merges into a topic branch tend to be only about adjusting to updated upstream from time to time, and this option allows you to ignore the individual commits brought in to your history by such a merge.

This option also changes default diff format for merge commits to first-parent, see --diff-merges=first-parent for details.
```