# Tortoise GIT - show changes created in branch after merge

Tags: git, git-merge, tortoisegit, git-log

Is it possible to show only commits and changes created in a specific branch? If I do this before merge it works. If I merge master branch to this branch (to make it actual) then I see commits and merges made in master branch. Is there some way how to filter it?

Answer (score 1):

You can do this using git bash (packaged tool with git), it's an alternative.
This is a more effective solution for this question:

- type the command:

```
git log --graph [branch]
```

- type this too:

```
git diff ..master path/to/file
```

Credits to the author @lukman [of this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14848274/git-log-to-get-commits-only-for-a-specific-branch/24901747) to a similar question here on SO.

Answer (score 0):

To see the branch before the merge, you can right-click on the commit before the merge on the branch you want to see, and click "Create branch at this revision".

Then browse references, and right-click on your new branch and click "Show log".

The merge is not shown because it's not on this branch. This works if your merge is the last commit, but if it isn't you won't see anything after it.

You can also branch off of your current branch, on rebase that branch to remove the merge completely. This would also hide it on log view (again, only because it's not there).

In both cases, the original branch is still the same.

In any case, there doesn't seem to be an easy way of doing this. A "hide other branches" option would be nice.

Answer (score -1):

- Go to github.com/"your repository"
- Select your branch from drop down.
- Click on 'compare' link on right side.
- Here you can see commits which are present in your branch and not yet
  merged in master.