# Git current branch commits list

Tags: git

When you do a Pull Request in Github or Stash you get a list of the commit from your current branch.

What would be the git command to get a list of the commit which makes up the current branch without specifying the name of the branch which we started from?

Answer (score 1):

You usually need to know from which branch you are coming from in order to list the commit specific to your current branch, as I explained in "[Git log to get commits only for a specific branch](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14848550/6309)"

Otherwise, you need to exclude the commits which are not part of only your branch (as [suggested](https://stackoverflow.com/q/14848274/6309) by [dimirc](https://stackoverflow.com/users/797033/dimirc)):

```
git log mybranch --not $(git for-each-ref --format='%(refname)' refs/heads/ | grep -v "refs/heads/mybranch")
```

Or simpler, using [`git merge-base`](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-merge-base) (if HEAD is *not* on your branch [as in this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/53569/6309)):

```
git log $(git merge-base HEAD branch)..branch
```

Answer (score 1):

In git it's not possible to only list commits for a specific branch without specifying *references* you want to exclude.

But you could determine the *references* programatically, such a command could look like this:

```
git log HEAD $(git branch -a | grep -v "^*" | grep -v "\->" | sed "s/^ /--not /")
```

For easier usage you could define an alias:

```
git config --global alias.branchlog '!git log HEAD $(git branch -a | grep -v "^*" | grep -v "\->" | sed "s/^ /--not /")'
```

And then just use it by typing `git branchlog`.

*Note: If you want to ignore `remote` branches, you have to remove the `-a` option from the `git branch -a` call.*

---

This command will log all commits which are ONLY reachable from the current *HEAD*. It achieves this by listing all branches (`git branch -a`), removing the current branch from the result and remote *HEAD*s (`grep -v "^*"` and `grep -v "\->"`).
In the last step it prepends `--not` to each branch to tell `git log` to exclude this *reference*.

*Note: Remote* HEAD*s look like this `remote/origin/HEAD -> remote/origin/master` and mess with `git log`.*

If you would type the command by hand it could look like this:

```
git log HEAD --not master --not origin/master
```

Comment: I tried the command on Windows git bash and get "fatal: unrecognized argument: ->" Any idea?

Comment: Please provide the output of `git branch -a`.

Comment: And tell me which git version you are using (`git --version`).

Comment: I am using git version 1.9.2.msysgit.0

Comment: ToNFluent  * bugfix/2029-freezing-for-a-moment    master    release/4.24.0    remotes/origin/HEAD -> origin/master    remotes/origin/ToNFluent    remotes/origin/bugfix/2029-freezing-for-a-moment    remotes/origin/master

Comment: I see, the problem lies in your remote *HEAD*. I'll edit the answer with a fix.

Comment: @LaurentKempé I updated the answer. It should work now.

Comment: I get a list but with far too much commits, but I got the idea of the command so I might adapt it.

Comment: It works perfectly fine on my system, what exactly does `git branch -a | grep -v "^*" | grep -v "\->" | sed "s/^ /--not /"` output for you?

Comment: I removed the -a  and get --not  ToNFluent
--not  master
--not  release/4.24.0

Comment: Okay, it's difficult for me to determine what your output should look like. Maybe you currently haven't checked out the branch you are trying to log?

Comment: I have checked out the branch. No worries you gave me the way to go, I will try to adapt and make it work on my machine. Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

Based on the above answer (https://stackoverflow.com/posts/26670064/revisions), here are a couple shell aliases:

```
# output the name of the current git branch
currentbranch(){
  if [ $(git rev-parse --is-inside-work-tree) ]; then
    git rev-parse --abbrev-ref HEAD
  fi
}

# log only commits that belong to the current branch
logbranch() {
  git log $(currentbranch) --not $(git for-each-ref --format='%(refname)' refs/heads/ | grep -v "refs/heads/$(currentbranch)")
}
```

Answer (score -2):

> change your current git branch
>
> **git branch** - > to list out the branches in the repos (***** indicates you are in that branch, your commits will come under this branch) 
>   if you want to see the commit of any of the branch then
>
> **git checkout branchname** -> change the branch which you want to see the commits then
>
> **git log** -> will show you the commits under the branch