# Php get Commit list of specfic Git Branch

Tags: php, git

I want to get commits of specific branch. following is my code

```
exec("git log $branch", $logs);
```

$branch may be master or any other branch. But this give all commits.

Comment: Possibly duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14848274/git-log-to-get-commits-only-for-a-specific-branch

Comment: i did not get satisfactory answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> But this give all commits.

Sure: it gives all commits reachable from `master` HEAD, which are *all* commit even if they are part of another branch. Up to the very first one (usually done on the master branch)

Even if you were to use another branch, you would still get all commit reachable from that other branch HEAD, even if they are part of `master` (assuming that other branch was done from one of master commits)

```
x--x--x--X           (master)
          \
           --o--o--O (anotherBranch)

git log anotherBranch = O-o-o-X-x-x-x
```

That is [why you need two parameters](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25801208/6309): one which will start the commit retrieval, one which will stop it:

```
git checkout mybranch
git log --all --not $(git rev-list --no-walk \
    --exclude=refs/heads/mybranch \
    --exclude=HEAD \
    --all)
```

Put that in your Php command, and you will get only the commits you are after.

Comment: @HardeepSingh Did you replace "mybranch" by your branch name? FOr the explanation, read https://stackoverflow.com/a/25801208/6309

Comment: i tried at my best to understand answer of suggest question. but stil i could not get success. i just want only commit list of one branch

Comment: i astonished that Git does not provide a proper way get git log Even if
Git is most common tool use by developers to sync their million projects

Comment: First, do you understand what a branch is in Git. Are the diagrams in my answer clear enough?

Comment: I know branching in GIT. But their answers not full fill my needs. i am actually creating a web based tool to sync my commit files to server, where git is not available. So i immediately need the solution.

Comment: So based on my diagrams, you would need the fog commits, not the 'x' ones, correct?

Comment: Sorry, i don't know fog commit

Comment: Ok OK i understood. Thanks VonC. you solve my problem. i  no need to get branch specific commits. i need to just checkout the branch before getting logs.