# is there a single command to squash all commits against the base?

Tags: git

I have a hacky shell script that I use to clean up the history on a feature branch when I'm working with people who don't understand how rebasing works and have hundreds of messy commits and multiple merge commits, meaning it is not possible to do a single squash or fixup interactive rebase.

This script basically creates a single squashed commit out of their branch vs what they are merging to, regardless of how they got there.

- this is not interactive rebasing [Squash my last X commits together using Git](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5189560)
- this is an automated version of [Git: How to squash all commits on branch](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25356810)

But it's really hacky, is there an existing git command that does this? Or is there a more idiomatic way to write the script?

```
#!/bin/bash  
set -e
if [ -n "$(git status -s)" ] ; then
   echo "ERROR: uncommitted changes"
   exit 1
fi
if [ -z "$1" ] ; then
   echo "ERROR: you must provide a base branch"
   exit 1
fi
NAME=`git rev-parse --abbrev-ref HEAD`
CUR=`git rev-parse HEAD`
TO=`git rev-parse $1`
echo "backing up your branch in bak/$CUR"
git checkout -b bak/$CUR
git checkout -b tmp/$CUR
git reset --hard $TO
git merge --squash $CUR
git commit --no-edit
git checkout $NAME
git reset --hard tmp/$CUR
git branch -D tmp/$CUR
echo "created a squash commit against $1 and rewrote your history"
```

Comment: I guess the best approach would be to fix your coworkers instead of fixing their messy commit history,... If that is not possible, I would do this: `git-log` all messages into a tempfile, `git-checkout` their latest commit, `git-reset --soft` to `git merge-base HEAD <branch to merge to>` and then `git-commit` with the contents from the tempfile. Not you can merge the single commit. Of course you lose all commit history with this approach. Another one would be to `git-log --no-merges` to `merge-base` and `cherry-pick` each commit... but merges are lost this way, which could break things.

Comment: that sounds like a multi-step alternative to the single script call that I'm currently using... why is that better?

Comment: You can put that into a script as well, of course. And it is even more simple (the `reset-soft`-approach). Also: No hard reset, so less likely to screw up things.

Comment: I already know about that approach, I linked to it in the ticket... I don't think it's as easily automated. Plus my script takes a backup of the branch before doing anything.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> ... is there an existing git command that does this?

No: it takes at least three to do what you are doing, in terms of the final commits and positions of branch names:

1. `git branch` to create a new branch name pointing to the commit identified by `HEAD`;
2. `git reset --soft` to move the current branch name to the target commit without changing the index and work-tree;
3. `git commit` to make the new commit.

To obtain the desired log message for the new commit (the one built by `git merge --squash`) takes additional commands.  To get `git merge --squash` to build the message *for* you, you must use `git merge --squash` or repeat its logic (check `merge.branchdesc` and `merge.log` settings, run various Git commands to extract appropriate strings based on those settings).

> Or is there a more idiomatic way to write the script?

Well, yes if you wanted to submit it as a contributed script to Git: then you would want to use `git-sh-setup` and a lot of lower level plumbing commands directly, and insert considerably more error checking (e.g., what should the script do when `$1` cannot be `git rev-parse`d correctly? what should it do in a completely empty repository where even `HEAD` is invalid?).  But that would make the script a lot more verbose—not quite a ~2000 line monster like the rebase code:

```
$ wc -l git-rebase*sh
     103 git-rebase--am.sh
    1042 git-rebase--interactive.sh
     169 git-rebase--merge.sh
     648 git-rebase.sh
    1962 total
```

but still a lot longer than it is now.

Besides that: In general, Git commands that do this sort of thing don't set up a backup *branch name* at all.  Instead, they rely on Git's *reflogs* for the branch names, and the `ORIG_HEAD` name that retains the immediately-previous setting.  If you were to omit the backup branch and use `git reset --soft && git commit -F $msg_temp_file`, you would get this same behavior—but once again you would have to construct the merge message in a temporary file.  Or, since both `git reset` and `git merge --squash` set `ORIG_HEAD`, if you were to use `git merge --squash` to create the new merge, you would have to use `git update-ref` to set `ORIG_HEAD` back to the correct value.

Both would change the observable behavior significantly, of course.