# gitlab: history of commits are available after merge request

Tags: git, version-control, gitlab

I have forked a project and doing some changes on it during several commits. I want to know if I submit a merge request, history of all commits are available to maintainer or not?

I'm looking for a solution which all commits are aggregated as one commit and I don't know if it does happen during merge request or not? This is because I have do some trial-n-errors and I don't like that these trial-n-errors be visible to project maintainer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, if you push your branch, all the history will be there. You can either

**#1 Squash all your commits before you push your branch:** see [Git: How to squash all commits on branch](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25356810/git-how-to-squash-all-commits-on-branch) how to do this

or

**#2 Squash all your commits on merge**: newer versions of gitlab have a feature that if you merge to master, all your commits will be automatically squashed before the actual merge:
[image: Gitlab Squash]

See https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/project/merge_requests/squash_and_merge.html for more information.

Personally I have done #1 before Gitlab could squash automatically. Now I do #2 all the time. If you don't want the history of all your commits available to the maintainer, you should do #1. Otherwise #2 will work just fine and the end result will be the same: One single commit for your changes.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, whatever you push, it will be the whole history up there. Some people like to squash commits before doing that. I see a lot of people using `git rebase -i` or `git merge --squash` for that. I like to do it by hand this way... say it's 10 commits you want to squash:

```
git reset --soft HEAD~10
git commit -m "blah blah"
```

Voila! There you have a squashed commit.