# How to squash commits from previous pushes to pull request?

Tags: git

When I type git log, I only get the last 4 commits which came after my last push. I can squash these but the problem is that I have had multiple pushes for this pull request, each with multiple commits. I need to somehow access all of these commits and squash them into one commit. This is on BitBucket but I would prefer the terminal commands.

Answer (score 0):

You could [squash all commits of a PR branch](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25357146/6309), then force push that branch.

But:

You can squash when *merging* your PR. That avoids having to do any local operation.

That feature is available on:

- [GitHub since 2016](https://blog.github.com/2016-04-01-squash-your-commits/)
- [BitBucket since 2017](https://bitbucket.org/blog/git-squash-commits-merging-bitbucket)

[image: https://bitbucket.org/blog/files/2017/01/2017-01-26-14-01-41.png]

See more at "[Why You Should Care About Squash and Merge in Git](https://blog.pairworking.com/why-you-should-care-about-squash-and-merge-in-git-675856bf66b0)"

[image: https://cdn-images-1.medium.com/max/1600/1*SodXuOEd1ScO4BcOLrp49g.png]