# How to squash commits with colleagues commits in-between?

Tags: git

I have a branch where I work since few weeks. Sometimes I go back on main to work on other features, and then come back to my branch.

While doing this, I `git fetch` and then `git merge` in my branch to stay up to date.

Problem : I have actualy `46 commits` that I want to `squash` but I have my colleagues's commits in between.

How can I `squash` all my personal commits on my personal branch ?

When I `git log`, i see my commits but also everyone's commits.

Comment: Read about interactive rebase, see here: https://thoughtbot.com/blog/git-interactive-rebase-squash-amend-rewriting-history

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/25357146/200609

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Posting the solution in case it helps :

i used `git rebase -i HEAD~<number of commits>` and it listed only MY commits. Just had to squash then.

Thanks for your help in comments.

Comment: It's a bit more complex because you have to know how changing `pick` to `squash` works and in what order/direction it will do the squash.  But you are on the right track.

Comment: I'm not convinced this should work because you said: "I want to squash but I have my colleagues's commits in between. Maybe if you changed `HEAD~X` to `main` it would work though?

Comment: This command prompt me only my commits, so it has been easy to squash them after that

Comment: Did it show all 46 commits, and none of the other people's commits? If yes, I think the premise of the question may have been wrong that they were in between your commits, unless the *only* other commits were merge commits, which fall out by default during a rebase.