# gitk: show branch name on hover

Tags: git, git-branch, gitk

Could you tell how to make gitk tool show the branch name on hover or suggest the tool which is able to do so?

gitk shows branches tangle where the branches are nameless, and I have to guess which is master, which stable etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the bottom left half of the gitk window, you have an information line specifying `Branches: dev, master, quux`. If you select a commit, that line will tell you which branches the commit is reachable from.

[image]

In practise that is all you really need to know; which branch it appeared in first is not really useful information given a standard git workflow.

As far as the order of the branches listed on that line is concerned, it also does not imply any kind of chronological order. It is apparently just alphabetically sorted.

Comment: You could extend the linehover function which currently just shows the parent commit subject line in a tooltip box when you hover over a line in the graph. However, frequently there are many branches and it would be no help to pack them all into a tooltip box. Clicking on the parent commit will show the branch list as mentioned above and that is likely the best display already. If you did want to try - `descheads $hoverid` would give a list of head ids and for each of those you can lookup the idheads array to get the branch names