# finding the branches that are available between 2 git commits

Tags: java, git, egit, jgit

I have a start commit from which i want to find all the branches till i reach another dont find a note for the commit.

```
commit 1
|
commit 2
|         commit5
commit3  /
|       / 
commit 4
|
commit 6
```

in this case say all the commit from commit 1-5 have notes "find branch"
and commit 6 doesn't have a not with that value.

So i will start with commit 1 find all the parent (ie: commit 2) and try to check if there is an branch for this commit (ie: number of children is more than 1). if there is more than 1 childs

1. the `getChildren()` method is there only for PlotCommit object, but the method `parentCommit.getParents()` return only `RevCommit` Object.
2. i want to find the branch name present in the particular commit

then when there is no more notes on the commit (ie commit 6 doesnt have notes) the logic will stop there and the collection of Branch name is returned

```
    Repository repo;//will be set as part of some other logic
    private Set findBranchesForCommit(PlotCommit parentCommit, String note) throws ExecutionException, MissingObjectException, IncorrectObjectTypeException, IOException {
        Set branches = new HashSet();
        PlotCommit[] parents = (PlotCommit[]) parentCommit.getParents();//XXX will throw exception as this return RevCommit[]
        for (int i = 0; i < parents .length; i++) {
            PlotCommit commit = parents[i];
            String result = extractExistingMessage(repo, "refs/notes", commit);//will return the if the note available for particular commit
            if (result.trim().length() > 0 && result.equalsIgnoreCase(note)) {
                System.out.println("#########"+commit.getChildCount());
                //TODO need to add logic to find the branch of the particular commit
                branches.add(""); //add the branches available for the commit
                branches.addAll(findBranchesForCommit(commit, note));
            }
        }
        return branches;
    }
```

**expected result**

i want to find the branch names of commits that contain a particular git note. in the above example the branch name of Commit 1 and commit 5 will be returned

Comment: I have problems understanding your question. Are you just looking for `git branch --contains commit6`?

Comment: In short. i want to find the branch names of commits that contain a particular git note. in the above example the branch name of Commit 1 and commit 5 will be returned

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While the git command for this kind of request (finding branches for a given commit) is:

```
git branch --contains <commit>
```

(as in "[Git: Finding what branch a commit came from](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2706797/git-finding-what-branch-a-commit-came-from)", and "[How to list branches that contain a given commit?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1419637/6309)")

it isn't implemented as is in JGit.

[This thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2706797/git-finding-what-branch-a-commit-came-from) has this to propose:

'`git branch --contains <commit>`' will report every branch which contains this commit.
In the standard push/fetch workflows for all commits you get from remote only "`origin/master`" is reported.
And even for local commits: Imagine you have merged your `feature` branch back to `master`. Then this command will report also the `master` branch and all `feature` branches created after merging.
Git simply doesn't store for a revision on which branch it was created.

> After these warnings: a rough implementation of "git branch --contains " could look like this:

```
Repository repo = new FileRepository(args[0]);
RevWalk walk = new RevWalk(repo);
RevCommit commit = walk.parseCommit(repo.resolve(args[1] + "^0"));
for (Map.Entry<String, Ref> e : repo.getAllRefs().entrySet())
  if (e.getKey().startsWith(Constants.R_HEADS))
    if (walk.isMergedInto(commit,
        walk.parseCommit(e.getValue().getObjectId())))
      System.out.println("Ref " + e.getValue().getName()
                                + " contains commit " + commit);
```