# See any Git commits directly to master?

Tags: git, branch, versioning

Let's say a dev team is supposed to commit all their changes to local branches, finish the feature inside the branch, followed by merging the branch into master.

How exactly can one find out if there were any commits made directly to master?

Comment: Before attempting to merge the feature branch?

Comment: Nope, after. generally we just have to know if anybody commits directly to master instead of their branch.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can fetch the remote repo, and have a look at the logs from master: if you see [commits which are only part of `master`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2706797/6309) (`git branch --contains <commit>`), then commits have been done directly on master.

You could protect your repo (if you have access to the server) against pushes to the master branch with **[gitolite](http://gitolite.com/gitolite/index.html)**.

Answer (score 4):

This will walk back the commit history of the branch `master`, taking the first/left parent of any merge commits (thus ignoring commits brought in by merges), and displays only those commits that are not merges:

```
git log master --first-parent --no-merges
```