# Git: can you get the branch a commit was first made in?

Tags: git, git-branch

From my master branch, there is a bad commit that was merged in at some point.  Is it possible to find out which branch it came from?

Answer (score 0):

If you know more or less when and where it happened, this a a neat visualization command:

```
git log --graph --decorate --oneline --all
```

If there is a lot of history and have no idea where to begin looking, your question has been previously answered in [Finding what branch a commit came from](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2706797/finding-what-branch-a-commit-came-from).

Answer (score 0):

### TL;DR

Yes and no. Commits carry ancestor history, but they don't actually carry branch information. Such information is *calculated* rather than stored or passed around as first-class data. You might find git-bisect a better option.

### Finding Branches Containing a Commit

You can use `git branch --contains <commit>` to find branches that contain the commit. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/1419637/1301972 for a more thorough treatment of the various options, as well as some discussion of the possible use of git-cherry under certain circumstances.

However, if the commit was merged in from a branch that has since been deleted, the ability to identify the original source branch will be limited to data stored in non-fast-forward merge commits. Therefore, your mileage will vary.

### Use Git Bisect Instead

In general, if you have a bad commit, you will want to take a look at [git-bisect](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-bisect) as a way to isolate the problematic commit or commits. This will let you do a binary search for good and bad revisions, and doesn't rely on source-branch information that may not be accessible in your currently repository.