# How to find out where did git commit originate from?

Tags: git

Got couple questions regarding git:

1) Is there a way to find out from which branch did commit (which was merged from dev into master) originate?

2) Also is it possible to find above information out after branch (where commit actually originated from) was deleted at remote and local?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Finding what branch a git commit came from](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2706797/finding-what-branch-a-git-commit-came-from)

Answer (score 1):

you can use `--merges` option

> ```
>    --merges
>        Print only merge commits. This is exactly the same as --min-parents=2.
> ```

and with a particular commit Id do `git log --merges <commit_id>`

Not sure I get the 2nd point of the question though

Comment: @R.P Regarding the 2nd part of the question, once the branch pointer is deleted both locally and remotely, then no, it will not be available, although the commits that used to be pointed by and be reachable from that branch pointer will still be there