# What command to use to see what branch my actual branch derived from?

Tags: git, git-branch, git-log

I'd like to see what branch my actual branch I'm on is derived from. I already took a look at the log but it's so noisy and I want to get 100% sure to find the correct branch in this case.

Comment: Martin Nyolt's answer is a workable solution.  A good practice to consider in the future is to name your braches with hyphens from the forked branch (i.e. development-newFeature).  Or alternatively, you could choose one branch to always branch from (i.e. dev always branches from master, features always branch from dev).  But utlimately, this is up to what workflow you decide.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This problem cannot be answered in every case.
Branches are not persistent: you are free to move branches around.
The reflog will allow you to see *some* history of the branch, but the reflog is only local and will be limited to 90 days (by default).

You can use `git reflog <branch>` to get the first occurrence of this branch in your repo:

```
$ git reflog branch | tail -n 1
03302d2 branch@{12}: branch: Created from HEAD
```

In this example, `03302d2` is the first commit of that branch.
Then, you can [find the branches that the parent of this commit came from](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2706797/1314743).
For example, you could do

```
$ git branch --contains 03302d2^
```

See the linked question for more sophisticated ways. But note again that this search is not complete and you may miss the "correct" branch.

Answer (score 3):

At the current directory/path of your local repository, Type command:

```
git log --oneline --decorate --graph
```

[image]
(Branch structure of repository https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot.git)

You will see the path of your branch.

Answer (score 2):

The following is getting close, but see **Limitations**.

```
git branch --contains $(
   git for-each-ref --format='%(refname)' refs/heads/ |
     xargs git merge-base --fork-point)
```

### Idea

We are using `git merge-base --fork-point` to obtain a fork point as a SHA-1. `merge-base` requires a branch name to check against. So you can ask what's the fork-point between master and my current branch fairly easy.

As we want to check against all branches we are using `git for-each-ref --format='%(refname)' refs/heads/`. We then get a SHA-1 back. In order to get a branch name we are using `git branch --contains`

### Limitations

There are quite a lot of limitations around that. It just gives you a good guess which branches a repository comes from, however for git it is hard to decide which branch something comes from. Take for example

```
       o -- o
      /     ^ branch-a
o -- X -- o -- o
     \         ^ branch-b
      o -- o -- o
                ^ branch-c
```

From which branch did `branch-c` come from? The commit marked as `X` i on both branches `branch-a` and `branch-b`. So it could have been from either of them.

#### Branches in Git

Branches in Git are simple pointers to commits. Every ancestor of the commit that the branch pointed to is part of the branch: e.g.:

```
a -- b -- c -- d <master
     \
      d -- e <foo
```

`a`,`b` are part of both `master` and `foo`, while `b`, `c`, `d` are part of `master`. However branches are just names to pointers. We can just set a new name to `d`.

```
a -- b -- c -- d <master
      \        ^bar
      d -- e <foo
```

Now everything on `master` is also on `bar`. Branches aren't versioned so we cannot answer the question where branches pointed to at a certain point in time. We therefore cannot clearly decide where `foo` was branched from. Git offers a reflog that keeps track of branch movements but expires over time.

#### Conclusion

The only save thing to say in git is the *fork-point* as a sha-1, due to the nature of branches being mutable. You can however rely on `git merge-base --fork-point` returning a SHA1 which is the actual fork-point.

Comment: Since `--fork-point` *uses* the reflog, this method is also not guaranteed. It's probably simpler to just search the reflog for the "created from" message. If that entry has expired, though, and `--fork-point` finds something, the "something" may be useful. Of course, you can also use the current merge base as a clue (and in fact that's what `--fork-point` falls back on if the reflog entries have expired).

Answer (score -1):

To add an alternative way.  You can also use git branch with `-v`

```
git branch -v
```

Which will list the originating commit in the second column.

Comment: This shows the current HEADs of branches, not any "originating" commit...?