# How to get a branch on which a commit is?

Tags: libgit2

Is there a way of getting the info about branch (using libgit2 library), ideally git_reference* from git_commit* ?

What I'm trying to do is basically a getting info about a branch from a commit.

Thank you

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Finding what branch a git commit came from](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2706797/finding-what-branch-a-git-commit-came-from)

Comment: I specifically tagged it as libgit2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, there is no way to do this.  Git commits are not "on" a branch, instead a branch is a pointer to a commit.  So the data storage goes the opposite direction.  As a result, many branches may point to the same commit, so there would be no way to get a **single** branch from a commit.

You could find all branches that contain a given commit, but due to the rather vague nature of this, it's not functionality that libgit2 provides.  You could certainly implement it yourself *using* libgit2, by `revwalk`ing the branches that you're interested in to see if the given commit is found.  But it will be very disappointing, performance-wise.

Comment: Hi, thank you for your reply. At least I know where I stand now. Best Regards