# Given a commit id, how to determine if current branch contains the commit?

Tags: git

What I'm trying to do is a version check. I want to ensure the code stays on top of a minimum version. So I need a way to know if the current branch contains a specified commit.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to list branches that contain a given commit?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1419623/how-to-list-branches-that-contain-a-given-commit)

Comment: See the proposed duplicate for how to find *all* branches that contain a specified commit. To find out if the *current* branch contains commit *C*, use the "plumbing" command `git merge-base --is-ancestor`. The current branch contains *C* if *C* is an ancestor of `HEAD`, so: `if git merge-base --is-ancestor $hash HEAD; then echo I contain commit $hash; else echo I do not contain commit $hash; fi`

Comment: Hi, please submit this as an answer so that it can be selected as the correct answer =)

Comment: @Ben - I added it as a community wiki answer.

Comment: @torek one strange thing i find is the docs on `--is-ancestor`: `Check if the first <commit> is an ancestor of the second <commit>, and exit with status 0 if true, or with status 1 if not.`. this makes me think the `if` in your snippet is the wrong way around since it exits with `0` for true but in practice it seems to work... could the docs be wrong or am I just reading it wrong??

Comment: @Remover: in shell scripts, zero is true, nonzero is false: the reverse of the C convention. `/bin/true` was originally implemented as `exit 0` and `/bin/false` as `exit 1`. (Modern shells have then built in.)

Answer (score 463, accepted):

There are multiple ways to achieve this result. First naive option is to use `git log` and search for a specific commit using `grep`, but that is not always precise

```
git log | grep <commit_id>
```

You are better off to use `git branch` directly to find all branches containing given `COMMIT_ID` using

```
git branch --contains $COMMIT_ID
```

The next step is finding out current branch which can be done since `git 1.8.1` using

```
git symbolic-ref --short HEAD
```

And combined together as

```
git branch $(git symbolic-ref --short HEAD) --contains $COMMIT_ID
```

But the command above doesn't return true or false and there is a shorter version that returns exit code 0 if commit is in current branch OR exit code 1 if not

```
git merge-base --is-ancestor $COMMIT_ID HEAD
```

Exit code is nice, but as you want string `true` or `false` as answer you need to add a bit more and then combined with `if` from bash you get

```
if [ 0 -eq $(git merge-base --is-ancestor $COMMIT_ID HEAD) ]; then echo "true"; else echo "false"; fi
```

Comment: That's not correct; the `grep` could result in false positives if `git log` mentions the commit SHA for other reasons, e.g. it's mentioned in a commit message as the result of a port from another branch.

Comment: Please see the comment on the question, which uses the built-in git toolset.  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43535132/given-a-commit-id-how-to-determine-if-current-branch-contains-the-commit/43535152#comment74126598_43535132

Comment: I like the first option, but to rule out Adam's objection, I would add the option `--format=format:%H` to `git log`.

Comment: @AdamSpiers If you're doing this programmatically, sure, but to the human eye it should be clear. git log messages are formatted so that the entries start with `commit 012345beef`, and then the content is prefixed by spaces, `____Adds lime to coconut`. So only if a line started and only contained the word commit and hash would it look suspect. Normally you'd see something like `____(cherry picked from commit 12341234)`. ***(Note, I had to put underscores because it renders the Markdown wrong if I use spaces.)***

Comment: When used in *detached head* mode repo, `merge-base --is-ancestor` worked while other options didn't. Thanks.

Comment: how do you search within remote branches? The issue is `git branch -r != git branch --list`

Comment: @AdamSpiers If you're concerned about that then use `git branch --contains $COMMIT_ID | grep "$(git branch --show-current)"`.

Answer (score 118):

Get a list of branch(es) that contains the specific commit.

```
# get all the branches where the commit exists
$ git branch --contains <commit-id>
```

Check if a branch has the specific commit.

```
# output the branch-name if the commit exists in that branch
$ git branch --contains <commit-id> | grep <branch-name>
```

---

Search the branch (say, `feature`) with **exact matching**.

```
$ git branch --contains <commit-id> | grep -E '(^|\s)feature$'
```

**e.g.** If you have 3 local branches called `feature`, `feature1`, `feature2` then

```
$ git branch --contains <commit-id> | grep 'feature'

# output
feature
feature1
feature2

$ git branch --contains <commit-id> | grep -E '(^|\s)feature$'

# output
feature
```

You can also search in both `local` and `remote` branches (use `-a`) or only in `remote` branches (use `-r`).

```
# search in both 'local' & 'remote' branches  
$ git branch -a --contains <commit-id> | grep -E '(^|\s)feature$'

# search in 'remote' branches  
$ git branch -r --contains <commit-id> | grep -E '(^|\s)feature$'
```

Comment: The `grep` here could also result in false positives if there are other branches containing the commit whose names also contain `<branch-name>` as a substring.

Comment: Yes @AdamSpiers, Updated the answer with exact matching the branch name by `grep -E '(^|\s)branchname$'`

Comment: Per [this comment on the related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2706797/finding-what-branch-a-git-commit-came-from#comment9642845_2707110) it can be useful to add the `-r` ("remote") or `-a` ("all") option to `git branch` to look for branches that may not be replicated in the local repo clone.

Comment: This didn't work for me, I needed  `git branch --all --contains <commit-id>`

Comment: Doesn't actually show all the branches for me, if I'm on master - it shows it & its remotes, if I'm in my feature branch - shows the branch and it's remotes, but not master

Answer (score 20):

Extracted comment by @torek as answer:

See the proposed duplicate for how to find all branches that contain a specified commit.

To find out if the *current* branch contains commit C, use the "plumbing" command `git merge-base --is-ancestor`. The current branch contains C if C is an ancestor of HEAD, so:

```
if git merge-base --is-ancestor $hash HEAD; then
    echo I contain commit $hash
else
    echo I do not contain commit $hash
fi
```

(Side note: in shell scripts, a command that exits zero is "true" while one that exits nonzero is "false".)

Answer (score 14):

To list local branches containing commit:

`git branch --contains <commit-id>`

and to list all branches, including remote only, containing commit:

`git branch -a --contains <commit-id>`

Similarly to check if commit is in particular branch:

`git log <branch> | grep <commit_id>`

and if branch does not exist locally prefix branch name with `origin/`

Comment: Voted up for the remark on `-a`. Thanks for that advice!

Answer (score 14):

Checks only in the local branches, that's been checked-out.

```
git branch --contains $COMMIT_ID
```

Checks in all the branch (local and remotes that are fetched)

```
git branch -a --contains $COMMIT_ID
```

Make sure to fetch the remote

```
git fetch origin
```

Answer (score 10):

Yeah another alternative:

```
git rev-list <branch name> | grep `git rev-parse <commit>`
```

This works best for me since it also works on locally cached remote branches such as `remotes/origin/master`, on which `git branch --contains` won't work.

This covers more than OP's question about just "current branch" but I find it dumb to ask a "any branch" version of this question so I decide to post here anyway.

Answer (score 3):

```
git branch --contains <commit-id> --points-at <target branch name>
```

It will return the target branch name if the commit id exists in that branch. Otherwise the command will fail.

Comment: nope... `error: malformed object name 'branch-name'`

Comment: You might get that error in 2 cases  
  
1. When the given <branch name> doesn't contain the given <commit id>  
2. The checkout <branch name> is not the given <branch name>

Comment: I think it changed, now if the target branch doesn't have the commit you get nothing, if the target branch doesn't exist then you have an error

Answer (score 0):

Since this question has some nice scripty answers, I'm adding my favorites.

This one will show you, for last `$n` commits in `$br` which branches contains each:

```
br=mybranch
n=10
git log --oneline -n$n $br | awk '{print; system("git branch --contains "$1)}'
```

This one is similar but does the same for a list of branches:

```
br="mybranch yourbranch herbranch"
n=4
for br in $brs; do git log --oneline -n$n $br | awk '{print; system("git branch --contains "$1)}'; done
```

Answer (score 0):

On a Windows machine on Windows/CMD terminal. You can do:

```
> git log | findstr "commit-id"
```

like:

```
> git log | findstr "c601cd6366d"
```

Answer (score -1):

Git checkout will return you to the branch of your current HEAD (current file) but it will not check out all branches. For example if you do a git checkout master the code will be checked out as if you were on master branch but it will not check out any files for changes outside of that branch.