# Comparing the changes in a tag with a branch

Tags: git

I get the latest tag with `git tag` and by sorting the output. Now I need to check if the changes in the tag are in an "X" branch.

I'm not looking for a magic command that can do this in a single step. I'm just trying to understand the overall process. For example, should I create a patch and then compare the patch to the target branch (if so, how?), etc.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43535132/given-a-commit-id-how-to-determine-if-current-branch-contains-the-commit just use your tag instead of commit id

Answer (score 2):

## TL;DR

There's nothing special to do here.  Just use the tag names in the same way you use the branch names.

## Long

First, a brief note: Git doesn't store *changes*.  Git stores *commits*, and each commit is a two-part entity holding:

- a full snapshot of every file, frozen for all time; and
- metadata giving information about this commit (also frozen for all time).

The snapshot is stored in a special format, with files compressed and (important internally and for disk space reasons) de-duplicated.  The metadata include things like the raw hash ID(s) of previous commit(s), and this is what sets up a Git repository so that the commits *are* the history.

That said, a branch name like `main` or `production` or whatever is simply a way to remember one (1) hash ID.  That remembered hash ID is—*by definition*—the latest commit "on" the branch.  Earlier commits that are "on" that same branch are those that are *reachable* by using the hash ID(s) stored in the metadata to step back one hop, to the parent commit(s), and then from all the parents, to step back one hop, to the grandparent commit(s), and then from the grandparents to step back one hop yet again, and so forth.

The result of all this hop-following is that in a simple chain of commits:

```
A <-B ... <-G <-H   <--main
```

the *name* `main` selects the entire chain of commits: all eight in this tiny example repository.  It *means* the last of these eight, but it *selects* the rest of them too, as long as you are using the "with ancestry" option.

No commit *contains* changes.  Each commit has a full snapshot of every file.  But, if we have Git *compare* adjacent commits—such as `G` vs `H`—we'll *see* changes.  Git can quickly eliminate exactly-identical files (because they've already been de-duplicated and Git knows that they're identical without even looking at their content), and hence need only compare the changed files, in a game of [Spot the Difference](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spot_the_difference), to show what changed.  Or, with `--name-only` or `--name-status`, `git diff hash-of-G hash-of-H` will show us just the names (and maybe status code letters) for the differing files.

When we have multiple branch names, there may be shared (common) *commits* / history, and unshared commits:

```
          I--J   <-- br1
         /
...--G--H
         \
          K--L   <-- br2
```

Here commits up through and including `H` are *on both branches*, and commits `I-J` and `K-L` are only one *one* branch.  Once we switch to one branch `br1` and use `git merge br2` successfully, however, we get:

```
          I--J
         /    \
...--G--H      M   <-- br1
         \    /
          K--L   <-- br2
```

The newly added *merge commit* `M` has *two* parents instead of the usual one, so now commits `K-L` are on *both branches*.  (Commits `I-J` are still only on `br1`, however.)  The set of commits contained within a branch changes dynamically over time, with ordinary single-parent commits adding one commit, and merge commits adding any number of commits simultaneously.

#### Tags are the same as branches

A *tag name*, in Git, has *the same internal representation* as a branch name.  It is just stored in a different [namespace](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Namespace), under `refs/tags/` instead of `refs/heads`.  That is, each tag name holds *one* hash ID.  This hash ID can be that of a commit—Git calls this a *lightweight* tag—or it can be that of a different kind of internal Git object called a *tag object* or *annotated tag object*.  These are "annotated tags": they still point to commits, normally, but they go through one layer of indirection, and the annotated tag object holds extra metadata, where you can store things like release notes (not really the right place for them) or digital signatures that tell us that this particular commit has someone vouching for it, with a cryptographically secure (we hope) method of verifying that (vs regular commit hash IDs which are [theoretically pretty breakable now](https://stackoverflow.com/q/42433126/1256452), though there are practical considerations that make this hard for Git commits).

In other words, a tag name finds a commit (usually: you can tag tree or blob objects, or even other annotated tag objects, but there are few practical uses for this and nobody really does it except as part of the Git self-test suite).  So in that sense, it's exactly the same as a branch name.  It just lives in a different namespace.

#### Tags are unlike branch names

There *is* a key difference between a tag name and a branch name, which we can express in two parts here:

- Tag names are not supposed to "move", ever.  If tag `v1.2` stores hash ID `H`, it should store that same hash ID forever.  But branch names *are* supposed to move and will even move *automatically*.
- Checking out a tag (with `git checkout` or `git switch --detach`) puts Git into *detached HEAD* mode.  In this mode, new commits you make have *no* permanent way to find them: as soon as you switch to some branch name, the new commits you made get "lost", unless you choose to save the current hash ID by creating a new branch or tag name.

In other words, branches are for growing—adding new commits—while tags are for permanent record-keeping.  There's one other big difference, having to do with `git fetch`: tag names are, by default, *copied* from other Git repositories, so that when you `git fetch origin` you get any of their new tags *exactly as is*.  If they have new or updated *branch* names, however, your `git fetch` creates or updates your *remote-tracking* names, not your branch names.

Hence our two key differences are:

- tags move and branches don't;
- tags are global (across clones) and branch names aren't.

Of course, we also run `git branch` to fiddle with branch names, and `git tag` to fiddle with tag names.  This keeps them separate in "ordinary user" territory.  However, the lower-level ("plumbing") commands in Git generally don't make this kind of distinction: we just have to spell out the names in full, such as `refs/heads/main` to mean *branch `main`* and `refs/tags/v2.3` to mean *tag `v2.3`*.

#### You're looking for `--contains`, or technically, is-ancestor

The `git branch` and `git tag` front ends both support `--contains` options, so if you run, e.g.:

```
git show HEAD~5
```

and see some commit that you think is important and should be in the release branch, or in release `v2.3`, you can run:

```
git branch --contains HEAD~5
```

or:

```
git tag --contains HEAD~5
```

to see if branch name `release`, or tag name `v2.3`, shows up here.

These operations really work by using the "is ancestor" test.  Remember how, after we made merge `M` *on* `br1`, *all* the commits in the drawing were contained in branch `br1`.  That's because, by starting at `M` and working backwards, we "reach" commits `J` and `L`, then `I` and `K`, then `H`, then `G`, and so on.  This means that each of these commits is an *ancestor* of `M`.  (For practical purposes Git also considers a commit its own ancestor, which seems a bit [vegetative](https://ucmp.berkeley.edu/glossary/gloss6/asexual.html), but, well, never mind ).  Git has a plumbing command for testing for ancestry:

```
git merge-base --is-ancestor <hash1> <hash2>
```

This tests whether the first given hash ID *`hash1`* is an ancestor of *`hash2`*.  The result is a shell exit code: 0 (true) means *yes, is ancestor* and 1 (treated as false by the shell) means *no, not ancestor*.

Hence, in shell script, a simple:

```
if git merge-base --is-ancestor $hash1 $hash2; then
    ... code ...
fi
```

is a simple way to tell if one commit is an ancestor of another.  If so, the *second* hash ID suffices to find the *first* hash ID, as long as we're doing commit selection with history (as `git log` or `git rev-list` would).  If `$hash2` is derived by finding the hash ID of a *branch* name, that means commit `$hash1` is contained in that branch.  If `$hash2` is derived by finding the hash ID of a *tag* name, that means commit `$hash1` is in the history of that tag.<sup>1</sup>

You can, at any point, use the plumbing command `git rev-parse` to turn a name, like `main` or `refs/heads/main` or `v2.3` or `refs/tags/v2.3`, into a raw hash ID.  There's a minor stumbling block with *tag* names here since they may point not to a *commit* but rather to an *annotated tag*, so you can use a syntax described in [the gitrevisions documentation](https://git-scm.com/docs/gitrevisions), where you add `^{commit}` to the name:

```
git rev-parse refs/tags/v2.3^{commit}
```

for example.

In scripts, it's often wise to use this separate `git rev-parse` command, as this allows you to catch errors, such as a typo in a name.  In more casual use, however, *most* Git commands accept names—with optional suffixes—where hash IDs would appear.  That's true for `git merge-base` too:

```
if git merge-base --is-ancestor $hash v2.3^{commit}; then
    echo "commit $hash is in the history of tag v2.3"
fi
```

For one-off commands, such as one-liner scripts you type in at a bash prompt, this kind of sloppiness is usually fine.

---

<sup>1</sup>This points up another way *humans* tend to use tags and branch names differently.  While the names simply select one particular commit, a human asking about a tag is usually asking about *just* that *one commit*, while one asking about a branch name is often asking about *all history ending at the selected commit*.  But not always!  Silly humans.