# How to check if a pull request is merged?

Tags: github, pull-request

I submitted my first PR and here is the screenshot of it after being accepted:

[image]

The messages say - ALL CHECKS HAVE FAILED
What to do next?

A detailed screenshot:
[[image][2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lyY4y.png)

It says "A branch or tag with name 'soumya' couldn't be found"
'soumya' here is the branch name I gave in my own repository. But cannot understand what goes wrong here.

Comment: Click o  that "continuous integration failed" and see the error

Comment: The tests failed and the branch has not been merged (and cannot be, until the tests pass).

Comment: In the timeline, the last entry is "AdityaSharma911 approved these changes 4 hours ago". If it had been merged, there would be another entry below it with text like "XYZ merged commit HASH into TARGET-BRANCH 3 hours ago". This PR, however, cannot be merged because of the failed checks. You should be able to click the Details button to see what it is complaining about. Note that once you fix the issue, and push another commit or force-push a replacement commit, you need a new approval.

Comment: @LasseV.Karlsen "Note that once you fix the issue, and push another commit or force-push a replacement commit, you need a new approval." That is not necessarily true. Don't say it. It _might_ be the case but no law says it is. It all depends on how GitHub has been configured by the individual company. So don't mislead a beginner.

Comment: Ah, sorry, I've never seen a git repository at work that didn't require it, but then I'm not responsible for configuring the repositories either. My mistake.

Answer (score 0):

## Did the checks fail?

Yes.

Red is not normally a sign of success :)

## If yes, what am I supposed to do?

Take a look at what the fail reason is and act accordingly.

What does that mean there?

- If the problem is obvious and you can fix it - make the change, commit and push to your branch (given the mention of prettier the code in the PR could require some formatting tweaks)
- If e.g. it's a transient error and you have the option to do so: rerun the pipeline
- If you don't know what to do - ask the repo owner what to do.

Note that pushing a new commit will also rerun the pipeline.

## Did the PR get merge?

No

The PR is still open, it has not been merged.

## How to find out?

The PR still being open is a pretty conclusive indicator it hasn't been merged, however in the general circumstance of wanting to know if a commit is in a branch:

- The PR is attempting to merge changes into Syknapse:master (Syknapse/Contribute-To-This-Project)
- Look at the [commit history for that repository and branch](https://github.com/Syknapse/Contribute-To-This-Project/commits/master)
- Note no reference to your PR

For a git cli answer see questions such as [Given a commit id, how to determine if current branch contains the commit?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43535132/given-a-commit-id-how-to-determine-if-current-branch-contains-the-commit)