# Finding the source branch of a merge commit

Tags: git

Let's say I have a feature branch called `feat` which got merged into the `master` branch:

```
master feat
  |     .
 (1)    .
  |\    .
  | \   .
  |  \  .
  |   \ .
  |    \.  <-- create branch `feat` from `master`
  |     |
  |     |
  |    (2) <-- make a commit on `feat`
  |    /
  |   /
  |  /
  | /
  |/
 (3) <-- merge `feat` into `master`
  |
```

How can I tell from the merge commit (3) what the source branch for that commit was (`feat`)?

I found that you can get a list of branch names given a commit hash by running `git branch --contains <commit>`, but then I'm still left with the problem that I don't know the commit hash of the last commit of the source branch (2).

[Finding what branch a Git commit came from](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2706797/finding-what-branch-a-git-commit-came-from) doesn't answer my question.

Comment: What if the branch `feat` was deleted in the meantime? In general this is not possible, a commit is not associated with any particular branch.

Comment: Finding parents of the merge commit would be trivial, but infering a branch name will be a speculative exercise.

Comment: You have the commit hash into the merge commit for example `Merge: a308437 ce271ef`, and the commit message contains the branch names. Hard to understand how you can have a merge commit without the information you need.

Comment: To get the *n*th parent of a commit, you can use the `^n` syntax, i.e. if `m` is the merge commit then `m^1` (or `m^`) would be (1) and `m^2` would be (2).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Finding what branch a Git commit came from](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2706797/finding-what-branch-a-git-commit-came-from)

Comment: @mkrieger1 No that does not answer my question. (Read the last paragraph of my question.)  The `feat` branch will not have been deleted at the point where I try to find it.

Comment: @Ôrel Well, I'm looking for a more bulletproof way of doing this that doesn't rely on the user giving out that information in the commit message. I've also been thinking about squash merging feature branches into the master and using commit messages like `feat: Add feature xxxxx` so the `master` commit history becomes easier to read.

Comment: Why is the name of the original branch something you want to recover? What kind of problem are you trying to solve by obtaining that piece of information?

Comment: @LasseV.Karlsen I'm using GitLab CI to automatically run certain scripts whenever a commit is pushed. When a commit on a `feat/*` or `hotfix/*` branch is pushed, a build for that project is created. Now when such a branch is merged into the master, the script should either deploy the hotfix build or the feat build. The script doesn't know which one though and that's why I need to determine the source branch name.

Comment: Existing CI build and deploy systems are sadly (and/or badly) flawed here. The only *really stable* name for a commit is its hash ID. A tag name is by-convention-stable. A branch name is in general completely useless, because the name may have been deleted since then—and worse, it might have been re-used for something else since then. Testing and deployment should be by hash ID, with perhaps some auxiliary database to make these more convenient for humans (i.e., the equivalent, or rough equivalent, of Git tags).

Comment: @torek Well, in my case I know that the branch will still exist because I would only delete it after the CI script has finished doing its job. And I don't re-use branch names in general. I usually follow this convention `feat/<unique-id>-<short-description>`.

Answer (score 0):

```
git branch --contains HEAD^2 --merge |grep -v master
```

If HEAD is the (3) commit from your schema,
`HEAD^2` will be the (2) commit

`git branch --contains HEAD^2` will show the branch with the commit
use --merge to only show the ones merged into your branch, then use `grep -v master` to remove the master branch

With a commit id this will be

```
git branch --contains baa46815a954779c78b722ade9d01a9da5781a58^2 --merge |grep -v master
```