# how to find out which git-branch a dependency in go.mod belongs to by command-line?

Tags: go, git-branch, go-modules

I want to write a shell program to check whether all go module dependencies in my project are on newest master version in their repositories. In particular, I want to know which branch each module is on. There is a file "go.mod" containing each dependency listed as `{module}-{commit time}-{commit ID}`. How can I get their git-branch name from SHA-1(commit id) or other message by shell program.

I have tried `go list -m -u all`, only showing the newest edition if the dependency is not up-to-date. etc. *git.xxx.com/project v0.0.0-20191119034146-e894bf51bdcd [v0.0.0-20200609070643-fd412b12b811]*. Without cloning the repos, can go module tools resolve this quetion?

Comment: What makes you think that SHA is associated with any branch name at all? Or that it's only one?

Comment: It's the commit ID of a branch of Git. Now the quetion is how to find this branch, without cloning the repo, by go tools or other command line method.

Answer (score 1):

I couldn't figure out how to find which branch the current dependency belongs to using only go tools. But there is a way to find which branch the commit is on using git.

`git clone <repo-url> && cd <repo> && git branch -a --contains <commit>`

Reference: [Finding what branch a Git commit came from](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2706797/finding-what-branch-a-git-commit-came-from)