# How do I find what branch (git hash) is deployed on gcloud?

Tags: git, gcloud

I've been given a nodejs API server project that was deployed to gcloud, but I have no idea what "version" is deployed there. That is to say I need to determine if a specific git branch has been deployed to a specific environment.

The version in `package.json` was not regularly updated.

I tried this:

`$ gcloud app versions describe 20220324t175829  --service default --project myproject`

I got the version by listing the versions on gcloud and using the last deployed. I see hashes for each file deployed, but those aren't git commit hashes as far as I can tell.

Is there a way to determine this?

Comment: Have you gone through this [stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2706797/finding-what-branch-a-git-commit-came-from)?

Comment: I don't think those shas are git commit shas, they are related to gcloud deployments

Comment: A gcloud deployment need not be anything that was ever *in* a Git repository, and in general it will contain at least one thing that was never in Git. It therefore doesn't have a Git hash ID of its own. *If* the thing being deployed has a version-dump operation, use that; *if* that dumps a Git version, use that in turn to find the Git version. But otherwise there's no general solution.

Comment: That makes sense. I think that's the answer. If you make it the answer I will mark it as such.

Answer (score 2):

As  @torek mentioned  gcloud deployment need not be anything that was ever in a Git repository, and in general it will contain at least one thing that was never in Git. It therefore doesn't have a Git hash ID of its own. If the thing being deployed has a version-dump operation, use that; if that dumps a Git version, use that in turn to find the Git version. But otherwise there's no general solution.