# How to find native/original commits of a branch?

Tags: git, github, version-control

There are two branches `master` and `A`. I know that some work has been done in the branch `A` a long time ago. Whoever was working on that branch, merged the `master` branch into the branch `A`, then merged the branch `A` to the `master`. All the branched are in remote. Now how i can find the commits that originally come from branch `A`?

**N.B** I am not looking for the branch name of certain commit. Rather I have the branch name and I am looking for the commits, so please don't mark it duplicate with [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2706797/finding-what-branch-a-git-commit-came-from) or other similar question

Comment: In Git before 2.36, this is pretty hard to do well in general. The new feature in 2.36 makes it easy *if* whoever built the branch obeyed some simple (easy to obey) rules, but without that Git version, your best bet is probably just to run `git log --graph` and try to follow the original branch's commits "by hand".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As described in "[Finding a branch point with Git?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71193866/6309)", that should be possible with Git 2.36 (Q2 2022):

```
(branch_A_tag)
     |
--X--A--B--C--D--F  (master) 
      \   / \   /
       \ /   \ /
        G--H--I--J  (branch A)
```

```bash
vonc@vclp MINGW64 ~/git/tests/branchOrigin (branch_A)
git rev-list --exclude-first-parent-only ^master branch_A
```

That will give you `J -- I -- H -- G`, which are the commits that originally come from branch A.

Comment: I have checked out to a new branch branch_A but getting this output https://i.imgur.com/2UhRBDS.png

Comment: @mahfujasif What version of Git  are you using? This option is only available with the recent 2.36.

Comment: Sorry i missed the version. My git version is bellow 2.36 and facing hard time updating

Comment: @mahfujasif On which OS are you? Windows, Linux, Mac?