# How do I get the corresponding branch name of a commit id in which the commit at that time was committed?

Tags: git, github

I have been looking for a solution for this since many weeks and it really drives me crazy.

**What am I trying?**

From an existing git project (it really doesn't matter which one), let's say for example the cpython project (https://github.com/python/cpython), I would like to get the branch name of a commit ID **at that time, when it was committed**.

---

**Let me try to explain what I want:**

Let's say during the development of a git project, the tree looks like this (**basic graph**):

```
----------------
o = commit
#xxxx = commit id
----------------

o (#abcf) <-- main
|
|
|
|            o (#bcdg) <-- dev
|            |
|            |
|            o (#bcdf)    o (#cbcr) <-- featureA
|            |            |
|            |            o (#cbce)
|            o (#bcde)    |
|            |            o (#cbcd)
|            |            |
|            o-----------─┘
|            |
o-----------─┘
|
|
|
o (#abce)
|
|
|
o (#abca) <-- initial commit
```

**So far so good:**

We can see, of course with our eyes, **at this time of the commits** which commit belongs to which branch.
For example commit "**#bcde**" belongs to the "**dev**" branch the same as for "**#bcdf**", and "**#cbcd**" belongs to the branch "**featureA**".

But the question here is: How do I get the branch name from these commits (**#bcde**, **#bcdf**, **#cbcd**)?

But also especially when the git graph during the development (what often the case is such as in the cpython project), you will find this **advanced graph** just like this:

```
o (#adfs) <-- main, dev
|
|
o (#aztr)
|
|
o (#awet) (Merge branch 'dev' into 'main') --─┐
|                                             |
|                                             o (#uisp)
|                                             |
|                                             |
|                                             o (#ulip)
|                                             |
|  ┌-----------------------------------------─┘
|  |
| /
o (#aukl) --─┐ (Merge branch 'dev' into 'main')
|            |
|            o (#dter)
|            |
|            |
|            o (#dnmj) (Merge branch 'featureB' into 'dev') ---─┐ 
|            |                                                  |
|            |                                                  |
|            o (#dwgf)                                          o (#epof)
|            |                                                  |
|            |                                                  |
|            o (#dolp)                                          o (#elop)
|            |                                                  |
|            |                                                  | 
|            o (#dujh)                                          o (#egol)
|            |                                                  |
|            |                                                  |
|            o-------------------------------------------------─┘
|            |
o (#abcf)    |
|            o (#bcbz) (Merge branch 'featureA' into 'dev') ---─┐ 
|            |                                                  |
|            |                                                  o (#cbcz)
|            o (#bcdg)                                          |
|            |                                                  o (#cbcy)
|            |                                                  |
|            o (#bcdf)                                          o (#cbcr)
|            |                                                  |
|            |                                                  o (#cbce)
|            o (#bcde)                                          |
|            |                                                  o (#cbcd)
|            |                                                  |
|            o-------------------------------------------------─┘
|            |
o-----------─┘
|
|
|
o (#abce)
|
|
|
o (#abca) <-- initial commit
```

As you can see, some new commits appeared, new merges, new "**featureB**", but mostly to note, that only the two branches "**main**" and "**dev**" can be seen. (Ok, sometimes you will still see the other branch features, but consider both cases where the branch name were deleted **and not** deleted)

So "**#uisp**" was in the "**dev**" branch, same for the branches "**#ulip**", "**#dwgf**", "**#dolp**, "**#bcdf**" and so on. While "**#epof**" was in branch "**featureB**", so for "**#elop**" and "**#egol**". And "**#cbcz**", "**#cbcy**", "**#cbcr**" etc. were in branch "**featureA**".

---

**What do I want?**

I would like, no matter if it is the **basic graph** or the **advanced graph**, to receive the branch name of a commit X **to that time, when it was committed**.

Example (let's say the command for achieving this is called 'magic-command'):

```
> git magic-command uisp
dev
```

```
> git magic-command dwgf
dev
```

```
> git magic-command elop
featureB
```

```
> git magic-command cbce
featureA
```

Of course now the question here is what branch name you will receive, if you would put the commit id "**#aztr**", "**#adfs**", "**#dujh**", "**#dter**", since it could be **main**, **dev** or even a **feature name** (or a combined form). Either it shows both or just really only the name "on that branch", I would be happy with both of it, so:

```
> git magic-command aztr
main (or "main, dev")
```

```
> git magic-command adfs
main (or "main, dev")
```

```
> git magic-command dujh
dev (or "dev, featureA")
```

```
> git magic-command dter
dev (or "dev, featureB", or even "dev, featureA, featureB")
```

---

**What did I try?**

I tried to use git log with its parameters, especially the "%d" in the pretty format, but this doesn't show the branch for each commit.

I also was thinking if the "symbolic-refs" somehow could help inside the "**.git/refs**" folder, since every commit the refs value should change during time, but I am not quite sure if this is the correct way, but actually I haven't seen any solution to show this ref changes inside a commit.

---

**Is it possible to receive the branch name of a commit X to that time, when it was committed?**

I hope you can help me with that problem.

Comment: You can't do this in general, based on the history alone, but you can possibly get the information on the machine that created the commit, by [searching reflogs](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2707110/184546).

Comment: Side Note, it's probably best to try not to care about this information. Whatever the reason you want to know it, there is probably a better way to accomplish that goal.